# When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?

Tags: updates, 2.3-gingerbread, android-versions

Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) SDK was [released on December 6, 2010](http://phandroid.com/2010/12/06/introducing-android-2-3-official-gingerbread-announcement-video-live-on-youtube/). ([High-level user highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html))

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 2.3, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2696/1465)
- [When will my tablet get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7680/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/1465)

Comment: Related: [Why aren't the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it's available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-wh)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded
4. If a new update comes out (e.g. 2.3.5 over 2.3.4), link to the new and don't keep the old information

Note that devices that do not meet [Google's Compatibility Definition](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf) will not receive a Google-sanctioned update.  In the case of the major manufacturers and many others, that means they won't release an update at all since Google's certification is important to their business.

## **Phones**

### Commtiva **z71**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Geeksphone **One**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Geeksphone **Zero**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Google **Nexus One**

- Official: 23rd February 2011. (According to a [tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/googlenexus/status/40221838743179264))
- Unofficial:

  - Without Market support: 17th December 2010.  (Via [Chris Soyars](http://ctso.me/2010/12/gingerbread-on-nexus-one-dagrons-ahead/))
  - 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Aria**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Desire**

- Official, manual update: 1st August 2011.  ([HTC UK Announcement on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=225607660802056) and [HTC Dev download center](http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Desire HD**

- OTA: 4th May 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/04/htc-starts-ota-gingerbread-updates-for-desire-hd-and-incredible/))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Desire Z** / **G2**

- Official: 29th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Droid Incredible**

- OTA: November 14, 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2011/11/14/htc-droid-incredible-owners-reporting-android-2-3-gingerbread-update-rolling-out-again/))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Droid Incredible 2**

- Official: 12th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/07/news/htc-droid-incredible-2-gingerbread-update-available-now/))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Droid Incredible S**

- Official:

  - OTA: 4th May 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/04/htc-starts-ota-gingerbread-updates-for-desire-hd-and-incredible/))
  - Canada: 29th July, 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone/))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **EVO 4G**

- Official: 6th June 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/06/01/evo-4g-gingerbread-june-6-manual-updates-june-3/))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **EVO Shift 4G**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Hero**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Inspire 4G**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Legend**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **myTouch 3G Slide**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **myTouch 4G**

- Official: 5th August 2011. ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Tattoo** / **Click**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### HTC **Thunderbolt**

- Official: September 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18077/android_23_upgrade_list))

### HTC **Wildfire** / **Buzz**

- Official: Never. (Official mail from HTC support; cause: doesn't meet the minimum requirements, e.g., 1 GHz processor)
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Huawei **U8220**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### LG **Optimus 2X / G2X**:

- Official: 29th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### LG **Optimus 3D**

- Official: 22 November 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/gingerbread-update-lg-optimus-3d-now-rolling-out))

### LG **Optimus One P500**

- Europe Official: 6th July 2011. ([Confirmed](http://androidos.in/2011/07/lg-optimus-one-gingerbread-roll-out-starts-in-europe-optimus-2x-3d-to-follow/))

### LG **Revolution**

- Official: 28 October 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/10/news/lg-revolution-finally-receives-android-2-3-gingerbread-treatment/))

### Motorola **Atrix 4G MB860**

- Official: 29th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))

### Motorola **Backflip** / **Motus MB300**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Cliq MB200**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Cliq XT MB501**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Defy MB525**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Droid A855**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Droid 2 A955**

- OTA: 24 October 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/droid-2-global-and-droid-pro-android-23-updates-pushing-now))
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Droid X MB810**

- Official: 24 October 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/droid-2-global-and-droid-pro-android-23-updates-pushing-now))
- Unofficial:

  - 12th December 2010. ([Information](http://androidcommunity.com/unofficial-gingerbread-port-for-droid-x-available-now-20101212/))
  - Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Motorola **Milestone X**

- Official: 26 October 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/cspire-motorola-milestone-x-receiving-android-23-update))

### Samsung **Droid Charge**

- Official: December 2011  ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/11/news/droid-charge-is-getting-a-visit-from-the-gingerbread-man/))

### Samsung **Galaxy Ace** / **Gio** / **Fit** / **Mini**

- Official: 4th August 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))

### Samsung **Galaxy S**

#### 1. Canada Bell **Vibrant GT-i9000M**

- Official 2.3.3: 15th September 2011.  [(Instructions)](http://pages.samsung.com/ca/androidupgrade/English/)

#### 2. Canada Telus **Fascinate 3G+ SGH-T959D**

- Official 2.3.3: 15th September 2011.  [(Instructions)](http://pages.samsung.com/ca/androidupgrade/English/)

#### 3. International **GT-i9000**

- Official:

  - OTA: <strike>16th April 2011.  ([Rollout started and then pulled in Europe](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/About-the-Community-and-Latest/NEWS-Update-for-the-Samsung-Galaxy-S/td-p/718863))</strike> ([Leaked download](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9336821&postcount=2))
  - Kies: Summer 2011.  ([Instructions](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I9000HKDXEU-support)) ([List of upgrades for each operator available via Kies](http://devsrom4android.blogspot.com/2011/10/samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-firmware-update.html))
  - 2.3.4 XXJVR via Odin: 27th July 2011. [(XDA update guide)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1139050)
- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

#### 4. US AT&T **Captivate SGH-i897**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

#### 5. US Sprint **Epic 4G**

- Official: 9 November 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/sprint-makes-it-official-gingerbread-epic-4g-pushes-today))

#### 6. US T-Mobile **Vibrant SGH-T959**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

#### 7. US Verizon **Fascinate** / US Cellular **Mezmerize** / C Spire Wireless **Showcase SCH-i500**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Samsung **Infuse 4G**

- OTA: Leaked 2.3.5.  ([Information](http://androidcommunity.com/samsung-galaxy-s-4g-and-infuse-4g-gingerbread-leak-available-20110923/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia Arc**

- Official (2.3.4): 18 October 2011 ([Confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-234-update-beginning-roll-out-xperia-arc))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia X8**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia X10**

- Official: 3Q 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/03/phones/sony-ericsson/sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-wont-will-be-updated-to-android-2-3/))

### ZTE **Blade** / Orange **San Francisco** / Dell **XCD35**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### ZTE **V9**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

## **Tablets**

### Barnes & Noble **Nook Color**

- Unofficial 2.3.7: 11th October 2011.  ([CyanogenMod 7.1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-1-released))

### Samsung **Galaxy Tab**

- Official:

  - Sprint: 5th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/07/news/gingerbread-rolling-out-to-sprints-galaxy-tab/))
  - UK: 29th July 2011.  ([Confirmed](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18709/gingerbread_anyone))
  - Verizon: 31 October 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/10/news/verizons-og-samsung-galaxy-tab-gets-gingerbread-update/))

---

This is not specific to Gingerbread, but this forum posts lists the rough dates for all Android versions for all Motorola models: https://supportforums.motorola.com/community/manager/softwareupgrades

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to include devices that ship with Gingerbread. The main reason for this question is to short-circuit all of the "when will {phone} get 2.3" questions. No one will ask that about the Nexus S.

Comment: Please only add information if you have a link to back it up.

Comment: Also see [Computerworld's JR Raphael's Android 2.3 upgrade list](http://blogs.computerworld.com/18077/android_23_upgrade_list)

Comment: http://www.icsforums.com/news/your-android-device-phone-not-get-update-why.html
discusses why some phones do not receive updates