# When will Gingerbread be release on UK HTC desire

Tags: htc-desire, 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

Does anyone know when the 3 network will release Gingerbread for the HTC Desire?