# Can I update the Android version of my Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I have Samsung GALAXY 2.2 & 
i want to know that can i update 2.2 to 2.3 or upper version update ?

Comment: Try this community wiki article: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread

Comment: As Matt says we have a central posts listing known upgrade dates to 2.2 Froyo http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo and 2.3 Gingerbread http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread , please check one of those for more details.