# When is the Nexus S Android 2.3.3 update coming to the UK

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

I have a UK Nexus S and it is still on 2.3.2. It's been a month since this update began being pushed out in the US, but so far I've seen nothing. Have any UK users received it, and is there any news on its UK roll-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offficial OTA updates can take their own sweet time getting to your phone, since they're dependent on not just how Google is rolling down the updstes but on operator arrangements as well. The simplest andquickst way of getting an update is to download the signed OTA update from Google and manually update your phone. XDA forums is typically a good place to find links to those updates - that is also how I downloaded my the 2.3.3 update to my NexusOne, sitting in India. Waiting for an OTA update, I would probably have been among the last people in the world to get it :)

Here is a simple way of manually updating your phone:
- Download the update and rename the file update.zip
- Connect your phone to your PC/Mac and copy that file to your microSD card.
- Power down your Nexus S. Then press ‘power’ and hold the volume button. You’ll see a screen appear with three Androids.
- Using the volume buttons, select ‘Bootloader’ and then press ‘Power’ to select.
- On the next screen, select ‘Recovery’.
- The phone will reboot. You’ll see a triangle with and Android robot and an exclamation point.
- Press the volume up button and the power button at the same time.
- Using the volume buttons, select “Apply sdcard: update.zip”.
- Reboot to get 2.3.3