# How can I update my Nexus S manually?

Tags: updates, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

I just bought a Nexus S from the USA and it works fine here (Spain). Just realised its version of Gingerbread is 2.3.1 though. While it's no surprise it finds no OTA updates with the local carriers, I wonder how could I get the phone up-to-date, *offline style*.

Suppose I don't have to root and tinker with it right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is the Nexus S Android 2.3.3 update coming to the UK](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/when-is-the-nexus-s-android-2-3-3-update-coming-to-the-uk)

Comment: not quite. I checked that question though my NS is from US, I reckon the official update should work for me. The question is just on how to apply it "non-OTA".

Comment: @flp As the answer on that question says, once you've downloaded the update from Google, rename it to update.zip, copy onto your phone's internal memory, power off, then hold volume up and power to reboot to the bootloader, using the volume key to navigate, select recovery, then use the power button to confirm, when you see the warning triangle and arrow, hold the power button and tap volume up, from the menu, select "apply update from /sdcard".

Comment: Just in case I've misunderstood what you're askin gand you want to know where to get the official non-OTA update.zip from, there are two of them depending which version of Nexus S you have: 2.3.1 GRH78 -> 2.3.3 GRI40 update is http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/e0b546c442bf.signed-soju-GRI40-from-GRH78.e0b546c4.zip and 2.3.2 GRH78C -> 2.3.3 GRI40 update is http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/98f3836cef9e.signed-soju-GRI40-from-GRH78C.98f3836c.zip

Comment: Well, what I want is to get my phone up-to-date :P An ideal answer would come with the downloads and procedures to get it done. When I started writing it, I had no idea what I'd have to download or install...

Comment: From the home screen hit the menu button, select `Settings`, scroll to the bottom and select `About phone`, then find `Build number` and please let us know what build number your phone is running right now.  As an example, my Droid is running FRG83D atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most OTA updates someone inevitably pulls the raw .zip file off some server and posts it online for others to use before they get the official OTA notice on their phones.

1. If your phone is currently on build number **GRH78** then download [this .zip file](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/e0b546c442bf.signed-soju-GRI40-from-GRH78.e0b546c4.zip).  If your phone is currently on **GRH78C** then download [this .zip file](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/98f3836cef9e.signed-soju-GRI40-from-GRH78C.98f3836c.zip).
2. Rename it `update.zip` and place it in the root folder of your SDCard.
3. Shut your phone off.
4. Hold down the **volume up** and **power** buttons at the same time to access the bootloader.
5. Use the volume keys to navigate to **recovery**.  Press the **power** button to select it.
6. You should see a triangle with an exclamation point in it.  Hold down the **power** button and tap the **volume up** button to access the recovery menu.
7. Use the volume keys to navigate to **apply update from /sdcard**, select it with the **power** button, choose `update.zip` and press the **power** button to start the update.
8. When the update is complete, reboot your phone.

(These instructions were taken mostly from http://www.intomobile.com/2011/02/24/how-to-manually-update-your-nexus-s-to-android-2-3-3/ except for the download links.  **I do not own a Nexus S and have not tested this personally.**  If these instructions look incorrect to you [or anyone else!] don't use them.  If at any step during the update process the instructions do not line up with what you see, you should stop proceeding and use menu options to back as far out as you can from the menus.  I'm not responsible for anything that happens to your phone, good or bad.)

Comment: Now, this is an answer :) Did. And just for the record; yes you can update from 2.3.1 straight to 2.3.3. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked!