# When will my tablet get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?

Tags: updates, android-versions, 3.0-honeycomb, 3.2-honeycomb, 3.1-honeycomb

Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) was released in February 2011, however not all of the devices that will get this update have received it yet. Each manufacturer and carrier needs to add their custom modifications before it can be officially released.  Versions 3.1 and 3.2 have also been released.

See also:

- [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2695/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/1465)

Comment: Honeycomb (ver 3.0) is a tablet only version of Android. Gingerbread (ver 2.3.3) is the latest release for phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

If you don't have a high enough reputation score to edit the wiki (currently 100), leave your suggestion in a comment or answer and someone will update the list.

## Tablets

### 3.0

Note: It is currently unknown whether any Tablet that was released with a pre-Honeycomb version of Android will ever see an official Honeycomb release. [Confirmation](http://www.unwiredview.com/2011/03/27/google-nexus-tablet-with-android-3-x-to-be-made-by-lg-android-2-x-tablets-wont-upgrade-to-3-0/)

**Samsung Galaxy Tab**

- Official: Never ([confirmed](http://www.unwiredview.com/2011/03/27/google-nexus-tablet-with-android-3-x-to-be-made-by-lg-android-2-x-tablets-wont-upgrade-to-3-0/))

### 3.1

**ASUS Eee Transformer TF101**

- Ships with 3.1

**Google TV**

- Logitech Revue products: 7th December 2011 ([confirmed](http://blog.logitech.com/2011/12/07/logitech-brings-next-version-of-google-tv-to-logitech-revue/))
- Sony products: November 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/10/news/google-tv-update-coming-next-week-with-honeycomb-and-the-android-market-in-tow/))

**Motorola Xoom**

- Official (US only): Early May 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/motorola-xoom-3-1-update-hitting-3g-and-wifi-models-both-already-20110511/))
- Official ([Non-US](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/blogs/tech-tech-boom-10017860/xoom-honeycomb-update-lags-one-step-behind-us-10024001/)): Early August 2011 ([confirmed (Europe)](http://www.eurodroid.com/2011/08/10/xoom-3-1-update-definitely-launched-in-nine-european-countries/))

### 3.2

**Dell Streak 7**

- Official: October 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/10/03/dell-streak-7-receiving-android-honeycomb-32-update/))

**HTC Flyer**

- Official: December 2011, starting with European GSM models ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/12/05/htc-begins-deploying-honeycomb-to-flyer-tablets/))

**Motorola Xoom**

- Official (US only): [August 3, 2011](http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/03/verizon-announces-android-3-2-update-for-motorola-xoom-3g-avail/)
- Official (UK): Late September 2011 ([rumoured](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/blogs/tech-tech-boom-10017860/android-32-coming-to-uk-motorola-xoom-in-september-10024146/))

## Phones

Note: It is currently unknown whether any phone will ever see an official Honeycomb release. [Google have specifically stated that](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html):

> Android 3.0 is a new version of the Android platform that is specifically optimized for devices with larger screen sizes, particularly tablets.