# Can I update my handset from gingerbread to honeycomb

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, 3.0-honeycomb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-3-x-update-honeycomb)

I am using  Motorola Fire XT. It runs on Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).
Can I update Gingerbread to Honeycomb.

1. Because it very slow in streaming youtube videos
2. Some times it strucking.

Comment: There are not currently any phones that have Honeycomb, it has only been released on tablet devices, and all signs point that it won't ever be released on phones. The forthcoming Ice Cream Sandwich is likely to be the next big upgrade for phones when it is released. See this list for all the currently known devices that can be upgraded to Honeycomb http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-3-x-update-honeycomb

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it, since Honeycomb is only meant for tablet devices. You'd be better off waiting for Gingerbread updates for your phone, assuming you're not running the very latest version, or for Ice Cream Sandwich, which is meant for phones and tablets.