# When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, android-versions

Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) was [officially announced](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-40-platform-and-updated-sdk.html) on October 19, 2011.

(You can review [the high level SDK changes in Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html) or the [official changelog](http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/) at the official Android Developer's site.)

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 4.0, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my tablet get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7680/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/1465)

Comment: Google has announced that only some of the newly released phones, probably in the later half of 2011, would be getting the updates atleast for now. Other devices like the Samsung galaxy s series may never get the upgrade.

Comment: @Kiran Do you have an source (link, etc.) for that?

Comment: https://supportforums.motorola.com/community/manager/softwareupgrades shows all of Motorola's Android devices and versions.

Comment: Engadget has a page where they're keeping up with pronouncements from OEMs: http://www.engadget.com/updates/which-devices-will-get-ice-cream-sandwich/

Comment: JR Raphael at Computer World also has a continuously updated list: http://blogs.computerworld.com/19341/android_40_upgrade_list

Comment: Should unofficial ROM hacks be added to this list? For example, I'm running 4.0 on my Samsung Galaxy S already, available from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1363593

Comment: @onik: Yes, within reason. I wouldn't add raw alpha versions. If it's a relatively complete version, indicate that it is `Unofficial` and link to where one can download the image.

Comment: Motorola explain why it can take so long to get updates like ICS out to people's devices: http://www.motorola.com/blog/2011/12/07/motorola-update-on-ice-cream-sandwich/

Comment: I bought a Nexus S in December 2011 with 2.3.6, 2 weeks later it was updated to 4.0.3, some weeks ago it was updated to 4.0.4.

Comment: @ott: Got something that announced it that we can link to?

Comment: @AlEverett I haven't made a screenshot when the upgrade notice came (I'll do that next time), this is a screenshot of the current system state: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/5201/screenshot2012070408233.png

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

Note that devices that do not meet Google's Compatibility Definition will not receive a Google-sanctioned update. In the case of the major manufacturers and many others, that means they won't release an update at all since Google's certification is important to their business.

## **Phones**

### Google **Nexus ONE**

- Official: *never* ([confirmed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/google/8848669/Android-upgrade-for-Google-Nexus-S-in-weeks.html))
- Unofficial: Oct 2011 ([alpha](http://thednetworks.com/2011/10/24/exclusive-android-ice-sandwich-hands-on-how-to-install-ics-on-google-nexus-one/))

### Google **Nexus S**

- Official:

  - GSM - T-Mobile (GT-I9020): Soon ([rumored](http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-s-ics-update-reportedly-restarting-few-weeks))
  - GSM - AT&T (GT-I9020A): Soon ([rumored](http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-s-ics-update-reportedly-restarting-few-weeks))
  - CDMA - SPH-D720: April 2012 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/04/24/samsung-announces-which-devices-shall-receive-ice-cream-sandwich-in-the-states/))

### HTC **Amaze 4G**

- Official: May-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/)), June 16th 2012 ([unconfirmed](http://www.tmonews.com/2012/04/t-mobiles-planned-dates-for-ice-cream-sandwich-upcoming-device-launches/))

### HTC **Desire**

- Official: *never* ([confirmed](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_releases_the_list_of_handsets_that_will_get_android_40_update-news-3974.php))
- Unofficial: November 2011 ([beta](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355660))

### HTC **Desire HD**

- Official: *never* ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2012/07/smartphones-2/htc-officially-pulls-the-plug-on-the-htc-desire-hds-android-4-0-update/))

### HTC **Desire S**

- Official: By the end of August 2012 ([confirmed](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/08/08/htc-desire-s-ice-cream-sandwich-update-still-slated-for-august/))

### HTC **DROID Incredible 2**

- Official: To be determined (by the end of August) ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **DROID Incredible S**

- GSM (international)

  - Official: 2012-July-2 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/07/02/ice-cream-sandwich-now-rolling-out-for-htc-droid-incredible-s/))
- Verizon

  - Unknown

### HTC **EVO 3D**

- Official: Early August 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/07/16/ice-cream-sandwich-headed-to-htc-evo-design-4g-and-evo-3d-by-early-august/))

### HTC **EVO 4G+**

- Official: May-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **EVO Design 4G**

- Official: 1 August 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2012/07/smartphones-2/htc-evo-design-4g-gets-updated-to-android-4-0/))

### HTC **Incredible S**

- Official: June-July ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Raider**

- Official: TBC ([confirmed](https://www.facebook.com/notes/htc/ice-cream-sandwich-updates-the-north-american-edition/10150786212353084))

### HTC **Rezound**

- Official: August 2012 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2012/08/02/ice-cream-sandwich-update-commences-for-htc-rezound/))

### HTC **Rhyme**

- Official: June-July 2012 ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Sensation**

- Official: March-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Sensation 4G**

- Official: March-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Sensation XE**

- Official: March-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Sensation XL**

- Official: April-Jun ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Thunderbolt**

- Official: 31-Jan-2013 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-thunderbolt-finally-gets-it-s-ice-cream-sandwich-update))

### HTC **Velocity 4G**

- Official: March-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### HTC **Vivid**

- Official: March-June ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android4faq/))

### Huawei **Honor U8860**

- Official: 12 January 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/12/12/huawei-becomes-first-manufacturer-to-push-out-an-android-4-0-update-and-no-the-device-is-not-available-in-the-u-s))

### LG **Optimus 2X**

- Official: 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2011/11/28/four-lg-devices-confirmed-to-receive-ice-cream-sandwich/))

### LG **Optimus 3D**

- Official: 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2011/11/28/four-lg-devices-confirmed-to-receive-ice-cream-sandwich/))

### LG **Optimus Black**

- Official: 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2011/11/28/four-lg-devices-confirmed-to-receive-ice-cream-sandwich/))

### LG **Optimus LTE**

- Official: 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2011/11/28/four-lg-devices-confirmed-to-receive-ice-cream-sandwich/))

### LG **Prada 3.0**

- Official

  - Germany and Italy: 4-July-2012 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/lg-prada-30-ics-update-now-available-germany-and-italy))

### Motorola **Atrix 2**

- Official Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **Atrix 4G**

- USA (MB860) Official Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))
- AsiaPac/EMEA/LatAm (MB860/MB861/ME860) Official: ([TBA](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **DROID 3**

- Official: *never* ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **DROID 4**

- Official: 2012 August 14 (phased update) ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/08/14/motorola-android-4-0-rolling-out-to-droid-4/))

### Motorola **DROID Bionic**

- Official: Early Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **Droid RAZR**

- Official: 2012-06-21 ([confirmed](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/22/3110142/motorola-droid-razr-maxx-android-4-0-ics-verizon-global-ready))

### Motorola **Droid RAZR Maxx**

- Official: 2012-06-21 ([confirmed](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/22/3110142/motorola-droid-razr-maxx-android-4-0-ics-verizon-global-ready))

### Motorola **Photon 4G**

- USA Official: Q4 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))
- Japan Official: [TBA](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c)

### Samsung **Captivate Glide**

- Official: 7 Sep 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/09/07/att-announces-ice-cream-sandwich-update-for-samsung-captivate-glide/))

### Samsung **Galaxy Note**

- Official: March 2012 ([rumor](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/02/12/galaxy-s-ii-and-galaxy-note-ics-update-to-be-released-in-march/))

  - AT&T: July 2012 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/07/10/samsung-officially-deploys-android-4-0-to-galaxy-note-att/))
  - T-Mobile: August 2012 (at launch) ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/07/17/t-mobile-finally-announces-samsung-galaxy-note-launching-with-ice-cream-sandwich/))

### Samsung **Galaxy S**

- Official: *never* ([confirmed (1)](http://www.theverge.com/2011/12/23/2657132/samsung-no-ics-upgrade-for-galaxy-s-and-galaxy-tab), [confirmed (2)](http://www.businessinsider.com/samsung-will-not-upgrade-galaxy-s-phones-2012-1), [confirmed (3)](http://thenextweb.com/mobile/2012/01/03/samsung-has-no-plans-to-deliver-value-pack-for-galaxy-s-smartphones/)) but Android 2.3-based firmware upgrade to give [some ICS-like features](https://www.facebook.com/notes/samsung-mobile/android-40-ice-cream-sandwich-upgrade-for-galaxy-s-ii/390405030989148)

### Samsung **Galaxy S Advance (GT-I9070)**

- Official: *unknown* ([Techzek](http://www.techzek.com/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-gt-i9070-review-specs-price-features/), [Slashgear](http://www.slashgear.com/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-due-april-30th-in-uk-26224805/), [Samsung Forum](http://answers.uk.samsung.com/answers/7463-en_gb/product/GT-I9070HKABTU/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-questions-answers/questions.htm))

### Samsung **Galaxy S 2**

- Official: March 2012 ([rumor](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/02/12/galaxy-s-ii-and-galaxy-note-ics-update-to-be-released-in-march))

  - T-Mobile: May 14th ([unconfirmed](http://www.tmonews.com/2012/04/t-mobiles-planned-dates-for-ice-cream-sandwich-upcoming-device-launches/))

#### Samsung **Epic 4G Touch**

- Official: August 2012 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2012/08/01/more-reports-of-ice-cream-sandwich-now-rolling-out-to-sprints-samsung-epic-4g-touch/))

#### Skyrocket

- Official: July 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/07/09/ice-cream-sandwich-hitting-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-skyrocket/))

### Sony Ericsson **Live with Walkman™**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia active**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia arc** and **Xperia arc S**

- Official: March - May 2012 ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/products/2011/12/21/ice-cream-sandwich-coming-to-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-smartphones-from-end-marchearly-april-2012/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia mini** and **Xperia mini pro**

- Official: June 2012 ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia neo** and **Xperia neo V**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia PLAY**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia pro**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony Ericsson **Xperia ray**

- Official: TBA ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/products/2011/11/15/ice-cream-sandwich-for-sony-ericsson-2011-xperia%E2%84%A2-portfolio/))

### Sony **Xperia P**

- Official: 17-August-2012 ([confirmed-official](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/products/2012/08/17/update-on-ice-cream-sandwich-android-4-0-software-upgrade-for-2012-xperia-smartphones/))

### Sony **Xperia S**

- Official:

  - Three: 29-June-2012 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/three-uk-customers-can-grab-android-40-sony-xperia-s))

## **Tablets**

### Acer **Iconia Tab** series

- Official: April 27, 2012 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/04/17/acers-expected-date-for-ice-cream-sandwich-update-to-iconia-tablet-is-april-27/))

### Archos **G9**

- Official: Early Feb 2012 ([official](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/blogs/tech-tech-boom-10017860/archos-confirms-g9-ice-cream-sandwich-update-schedule-10025196/))

### ASUS **Eee Pad Transformer**

- Official: Feb 23rd (Feb 24th for North America) ([official](http://www.engadget.com/2012/02/23/asus-transformer-tf101-finally-receives-ics-update-taiwan-takes/))

### ASUS **Transformer Prime**

- Official: January 2012 ([rumour](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/12/12/asus-transformer-prime-to-receive-android-4-0-next-month/))

### HTC **Flyer**

- Official: Q1 2012 ([rumour](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/01/23/htc-flyer-rumored-to-see-android-4-0-in-q1/))

### Lenovo **Thinkpad Tablet**

- Official: May 2012 ([offical source](http://blog.lenovo.com/products/android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-thinkpad-tablet))

  - U.S.: 1-July-2012 ([confirmed](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/27/3120263/lenovo-thinkpad-tablet-android-4-us-update))

### Lenovo **Ideapad K1**

- Official: June 15 2012 (working date) download (not OTA update) ([source](http://forum.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-IdeaTab-Slate-Tablets/Ice-Cream-Sandwich-for-Ideapad-K1/m-p/760833#M7924))

### Motorola **XOOM**

- Official:

  - US Wifi models - Mid Jan 2012  ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/01/18/motorola-xoom-wifi-get-on-board-because-the-ice-cream-sandwich-update-is-happening/))
  - non-US Wifi models - Q2 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

    - UK: August 2012 ([confirmed](http://eurodroid.com/2012/08/07/xoom-wi-fi-and-3g-models-now-getting-android-4-0-update-in-the-uk/))
  - US 3G models - Q2 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))
  - non-US 3G models - ([TBC](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

    - UK: August 2012 ([confirmed](http://eurodroid.com/2012/08/07/xoom-wi-fi-and-3g-models-now-getting-android-4-0-update-in-the-uk/))
- Unofficial:

  - US 3G/LTE models ([CyanogenMod "Kang"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=7288f84f52b0148987215489c04966a7&t=1437358), [Team Eos](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=7288f84f52b0148987215489c04966a7&t=1484770))

### Motorola **XOOM Family Edition**

- Official: Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **XOOM 2**

- Official: Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **XOOM 2 Media Edition**

- Official: Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **XYBOARD 8.2**

- Official: Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Motorola **XYBOARD 10.1**

- Official: Q3 2012 ([confirmed](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

### Samsung **Galaxy Tab Plus 7.0**

- Official: 3 August 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0-plus-ics-update-rolling-out-20120803/))

  - Austria: July 2012 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2012/07/10/samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0-plus-receives-ice-cream-sandwich-in-austria/))

### Samsung **Galaxy Tab 7.7**

- Official: 4-July-2012 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2012/07/04/samsung-galaxy-tab-7-7-ice-cream-sandwich-update-available-via-kies/))

### Samsung **Galaxy Tab 8.9**

- Official: August 2012 ([official](http://www.pcworld.com/article/257960/samsung_galaxy_tabs_to_get_ice_cream_sandwich_upgrade_by_august.html))

### Samsung **Galaxy Tab 10.1**

- Official: August 2012 ([official](http://www.pcworld.com/article/257960/samsung_galaxy_tabs_to_get_ice_cream_sandwich_upgrade_by_august.html))

### Toshiba **Thrive**

- Official: 3Q 2012 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/toshiba-thrive-android-4-0-ics-update-gets-delayed-coming-this-fall-20120622/))

Comment: Devices that are getting Gingerbread updates that add some ICS features should not be added here. Only devices that are actually getting Ice Cream Sandwich should be listed.

Comment: Be great if we could have confirmation of some of these dates... i.e. have people actually been able to upgrade to ICS and what date did it occur. Or should this be on another question?

Comment: @Michael: I don't think that would be very useful. Updates generally roll out over days or weeks. Further, it's one person's word, where we prefer to link to Android news sites. And you've got to figure that multiple people will chime in; what good is a dozen "me too" posts?

Comment: Motorola has fallen back on the Atrix 4G: https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c

Answer (score 9):

Droid-Life keeps an up-to-date listing of many of these phones which shows also when there are delays or exceptions such as was the case with Bionic. Their list can be found here http://www.droid-life.com/2012/05/22/when-is-my-android-phone-getting-ice-cream-sandwich-verizon/