# Samsung Galaxy S2 support for Android 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich) post indicates that `Samsung Galaxy S2` may get Android 4.0. I am planning to buy `S2` and I have the following questions.

1. Is `Galaxy S2` compatible to run `Android 4.0`?
2. If Samsung is not releasing `Android 4.0` for `Galaxy S2`, is there a way that I can install it manually? Will that cause any issues?
3. Will installing Android manually affects the phone warranty?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific document describing the official requirements of ICS called the "[Android 4.0 Compatibility definition](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf)". You can compare this to the phone's specs to see if it matches the official requirements and hope that Samsung continues to support your device long enough to upgrade it to ICS.

If not, your only hope is for an unofficial port of ICS, similar to [Teamhacksung's ICS Port](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1363593) for the original Galaxy S. These are not officially supported and will cause you to void your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

According to Samsung UK it will be getting ICS, so I'd say that it has to be compatible.

Quote from [Samsung UK's twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/samsunguk/status/136838488954912768): `Hi, good news - the Galaxy S II will be receiving ICS, but there are no dates confirmed as yet. We will keep you posted.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's compatible.

Maybe this can help you:

[Installing Android ICS 4.0.3 on Samsung Galaxy SII](http://softwareisart.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/installing-android-403-ice-cream.html)