# How can I root my HTC Incredible S?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, htc-incredible-s

I have an HTC Incredible S and want to install Ice Cream Sandwich, which I don't think is officially available right now. How can I root it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

Answer (score 1):

Doing a simple [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=rooting+%22htc+incredible+s%22) provides you with a list of How-Tos:

- [How to Root HTC Incredible S](http://support.evanhe.com/2012/02/10/how-to-root-htc-incredible-s/)
- [How To Root Your HTC Incredible S](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-root-your-htc-incredible-s-34854/)
- [How to Root HTC Incredible S](http://www.android.gs/root-htc-incredible-s/)
- [All-in-One S-Off and Root Method for Incredible S](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/all-in-one-s-off-and-root-method-for-incredible-s/)

Even video tutorials are found:

- [Root Your HTC Incredible pt 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBLLjAAdmuQ)
- [Howto Unlock HTC Incredible S + CyanogenMod 7 Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8TZ_RKd3aE) (part 2 and 3 are linked there)

With so many sources available, you should be able to find what you're looking for. And in case it's all to scary: We already have August, so...

- [HTC Incredible S to receive Ice Cream Sandwich update by end of August](http://mobilesyrup.com/2012/08/10/htc-incredible-s-to-receive-ice-cream-sandwich-update-by-end-of-august/)

Comment: While references are fine, we want to be a self-contained resource.  Per the FAQ, answers that are mostly links may be removed: [http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion)

Comment: @MatthewRead See the list of "possible duplicates" above? I just wanted to point out that the question would be easy to answer by an easy Google search. Sure I could have simply said so -- so the links are just giving evidence. You know I usually don't give "link only" answers.

Comment: I'm not concerned with "usually", just these instances (went through all the rooting questions linked in the list today).  I've cleaned up the question comments that are no longer relevant due to the policy change on 1-question-per-device vs the 1-giant-root-everything-post.

Comment: bootloader by htc: http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/