# Is Samsung Galaxy Tab P7300 upgradable to Android 4?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab-8.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

I am looking into buying this: http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P7310MAAXAR

I am wondering if I can upgrade the 3.2 version of Android to 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes:

> Samsung Electronics plan to provide the Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich
>   update for GALAXY devices. The platform update for GALAXY S II and
>   GALAXY Note will start in the first quarter 2012, and other GALAXY
>   devices will soon follow.
>
> The ICS-upgradable devices are the GALAXY S II, GALAXY S II LTE,
>   GALAXY Note, GALAXY R, GALAXY Tab 10.1, GALAXY Tab 8.9, GALAXY Tab
>   7.7, and GALAXY Tab 7.0 Plus.
>
> For upgradable models, Samsung will make separate announcements on
>   details of OS updates schedule for each market according to market
>   situation and carriers' requirements. [December 20, 2011] From AT&T:
>   We plan for both the [HTC] Vivid and [Samsung] Galaxy S II Skyrocket
>   to be upgraded to Ice Cream Sandwich.

http://www.engadget.com/updates/which-devices-will-get-ice-cream-sandwich/