# Any information on when ICS will be available for the Nexus S GT-I9020A (AT&T/Fido/Rogers)

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, att

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

I know the version for [T-Mobile (GT-I9020 or GT-I9020T)](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-manually-update-your-gsm-nexus-s-ice-cream-sandwich) Nexus S has been available for download since December, but is there any information on when a similar update will be available for the AT&T/Fido/Rogers (GT-I9020A) Nexus S?