# Samsung galaxy S2 can't upgrade to 4.0

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

i have Samsung galaxy s2 with android 2.3.6 and when i try update it with Kies to 4.0 (ice cream sandwhich) it shows that I9100XXKL1/I9100OXAKL1/I9100XXKL1/I9100XXKL1 (KOR) can't be updated.

This is old phone, broken android or i should wait for update?

Answer (score 3):

Just wait, it takes a few weeks before everybody gets the update... And it was first released two days ago... So if you don't have it in two weeks, write back :)