# Ice Cream Sandwich OTA on Nexus S?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-nexus-s, ota-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

So the OTA Ice Cream Sandwich deployment for Samsung Nexus S was stopped because the deployed version caused too much problems. Does somebody knows if another corrected version is another debugged version is to be deployed OTA anytime soon?

Comment: So for those who are interested: http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-s-ics-update-reportedly-restarting-few-weeks

Comment: I just realized the refered question "When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?" didn't contained the answer to my question when I asked it. Somebody changed it to add the answer I needed, so actually it was NOT a duplicate at the time. Thank you anyway...