# My Sensation is running 2.3.4, why hasn't this updated?

Tags: updates, htc-sensation

I've got a HTC Sensation 3G, and I'm waiting for the [Android 4 Update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich).

I understand this update might not be available for my handset yet, but I checked my `Android Version` and I'm currently running 2.3.4.

Shouldn't this be 3.x at the moment?

I've checked for updates, but my device can't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android 3.x is reserved for Tablets, and so would never be running on an actual phone. As for 4.x, it's basically a waiting game. If there have been assurances from HTC that the update will eventually be available for your phone, you'll just have to wait until your phone tells you it's available.  The only way to speed things up would be to monitor the forums and see when others have gotten the same update.  Then you'll have a chance to download it yourself and tell your recovery to install it.  Even then its still a waiting game.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So `2.3.4` isn't a really outdated version then? I was just concerned I wouldn't get `4.x` because I haven't even been prompted for `2.9` etc..

Comment: No problems.  I hate to say it but you are a bit out of date.  For example, the latest version of Android 2.3 is 2.3.7, however you can rest assured.  The newer versions were to resolve specific issues on certain phones. Although it doesn't list release dates on specific phones, a quick site to use to track version history is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history .

Comment: Cheers for that, and don't worry I don't forget :)

Comment: @Curt As a UK user on T-Mobile I received my Sensation 4.0 update last night :)