# Are there any other launchers that display a folder's contents instead of the generic icon?

Tags: launcher, home-screen-folders

The Xperia Neo V stock launcher displays a 2x2 grid containing the first 4 apps that a folder contains instead of a simple icon. Is there any other launcher that does this or something similar?

Comment: The stock Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4) launcher has something similar built in (it shows a cascaded view of the first three icons in the folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help people who are still waiting for [their phone to be upgraded](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich), but the stock Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4) launcher has something similar built in - it shows a cascaded view of the first three icons in the folder.

[image: folders on a home screen in ICS on a Galaxy Nexus]

Answer (score 1):

[ADWLauncher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adwfreak.launcher) has this feature as well. It can display either a generic folder icon or a circle with the apps within it much like stock Ice Cream Sandwich.

To change from Folder Icons to the Preview Icons:

1. Go to your home screen
2. Hit the Menu Key
3. Go to `ADWSettings`
4. Go to `UI Settings`

   [image: Folder Option]
5. Go to `Folders`
6. Make sure `Show Contents` is checked

   [image: Options Within Folder]

Comment: Where is the setting for this?

Comment: Edited to show where to find this option

Comment: The `folders` section or submenu doesn't exist on my device. Are you running ICS?

Comment: I run Gingerbread and ICS and it showed up on both. It may be that I have the paid (ADWLauncer EX) version and it is not in the free version.