# Can I install Ice Cream Sandwich on my HTC Wildfire?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, installation, htc-wildfire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Please, I want to install Ice Cream Sandwich on my HTC Widlfire, can I do?
If I can, how?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt it, but take a look at the new CM9 release of [CyanogenMod](http://CyanogenMod.com) and see if the Wildfire is supported. I have the HTC Desire and haven't bothered checking as I'm happy with CM7 (Gingerbread) but I think the Desire is missing some needed hardware features and as the Wildfire is lower specked than the Desire it is probably not going to be supported either.

Comment: It's not missing any features. As far as I'm aware everything except camera and HW decoded video playback is working on the desire. It's more than capable of running ICS.