# Can I update my Nexus One to Android 4.0, and how do I do it?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

I've never even used Android before, and I've been given this Nexus One for app development by my supervisor.

I'd like to get it updated to Android 4.0 from 2.3.x, but I'm not sure how and I can't find clear-cut instructions.

Can it even be done?

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich . There is no official update for the Nexus One. Your only option will be a custom ROM.

Comment: @AlEverett I'm not familiar with the concept of a "custom ROM." Can you link some resources?

Comment: @Aerovistae for a quick start on the terminology, see this previous question: [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/) some resources for finding custom roms for your device: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/)