# Upgrade Samsung Galaxy II  to Android 4.0?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Is it possible to upgrade Samsung Galaxy SII's Android 2.3 to Android 4.0? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: ready to try out other stuff like custome roms ? S2 has the most number of CR out there, and i can assure every one of them will be better than the official Samsung update. Speaking from personal experience with Galaxy Note

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich

Answer (score 3):

Samsung has released an official update to 4.0.3, just do the normal update procedure with Kies or OTA. There may be some delay on the release based on your region but it either should be available already or coming really soon.

Comment: Is the update for the `I9100G` or for the older version of the S2?

Comment: At least for the I9100, not sure about the G variant.