# How to upgrade Samsung Galaxy S2 to ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade Samsung Galaxy II OS to android 4.0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24293/upgrade-samsung-galaxy-ii-os-to-android-4-0)

I want to know if there is any official documentation on how to upgrade Samsung's Android enabled devices?

Comment: Can we get region and carrier information, in order to answer this more effectively? Basically the three easy options are OTA, ODIN or Kies, though.

Comment: I'd consider only OTA and Kies as "easy", especially as the question is this vague. Plus, he's asking for official documentation, so warranty might be a factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your device is not rooted since you did not mention it. For non-rooting device you just have to wait for the Over The Air (OTA) update from Samsung or your network provider.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation can only come from your carrier, or if you bought it sim-free, then from your country's Samsung website.

Answer (score 0):

Ota is definitely going to be the "easiest" but you aren't guaranteed to ever get the update. If you want to get ICS as soon as possible, I'd recommend flashing [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices) ([full update guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II%3a_Full_Update_Guide) for the S2), downloads are [here](http://get.cm/?device=galaxys2). Believe version CM9 is ICS 4.0.4, and CM10 (aka. Jelly Bean) is also [available](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1419102) as nightly builds. I've heard some great things about it.

But... that may not be what you are looking for if you are trying to go completely stock...