# Android 4 for Galaxy S Advance (GT-I9070)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

Does Samsung provide an update to Android 4 for GT-I9070 Galaxy S Advance?

Answer (score 3):

Both [Techzek](http://www.techzek.com/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-gt-i9070-review-specs-price-features/) and [Slashgear](http://www.slashgear.com/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-due-april-30th-in-uk-26224805/) have stated (in semi-recent articles) that Samsung has not said if the device will get the ICS upgrade or not, and Samsung seems to be ignoring the issue judging by the amount of ignored questions on this topic in [it's own forum](http://answers.uk.samsung.com/answers/7463-en_gb/product/GT-I9070HKABTU/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-questions-answers/questions.htm).