# When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, android-versions

Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) was announced at **Google I|O 2012** on June 27, 2012.

(You can review [the high level changes in Android 4.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#android-41) at the official Android Developer's site.)

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 4.1, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.2 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32589/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684/1465)

Comment: JBQ has made the source to Android 4.1 available around 48hours ago and CM are "merging" manually the changes to the source base.

Comment: Here's [an article from Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/will-my-phone-or-tablet-get-jelly-bean-and-when) which talks a bit about why updates aren't just automatically added to devices that can probably handle it as well as some speculation about some popular and recent devices.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it's available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-wh)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the **manufacturer** and **model**
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

Note that devices that do not meet Google's Compatibility Definition will not receive a Google-sanctioned update. In the case of the major manufacturers and many others, that means they won't release an update at all since Google's certification is important to their business.

## **Phones**

### Asus

#### Padfone

- Official: 2013-03-25 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/24824/original-asus-padfone-gets-android-4-1-1-jelly-bean/))

### Google

#### Nexus S

- Official: mid-July ([confirmed](http://live.theverge.com/google-io-2012-live-blog-day-one/))

### HTC

#### Desire C

- Official: Never ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android41faq/))

#### One S

- Official: *unknown date* ([confirmed](http://www.slashgear.com/htc-confirms-jelly-bean-for-one-x-one-s-and-one-xl-incoming-20239483/))

#### One V

- Official: Never ([confirmed](http://www.htc.com/www/help/android41faq/))

#### One VX

- AT&T: 2013-08-02 ([announced](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/02/att-htc-one-vx-receiving-android-4-1-update-starting-today-build-2-21-502-1/))

#### One X

- Official: 2013-03-07 ([confirmed](http://blogs.att.net/consumerblog/story/a7787934))

#### One XL

- Official: *unknown date* ([confirmed](http://www.slashgear.com/htc-confirms-jelly-bean-for-one-x-one-s-and-one-xl-incoming-20239483/))

### LG

#### Optimux 4X HD (P880)

- Official: 2013-04-07 [MyLGPhones.Com](http://www.mylgphones.com/android-4-1-jelly-bean-firmware-update-for-lg-optimus-4x-hd.html)

#### Optimus G

- Sprint: *2013-March* ([confirmed](http://community.sprint.com/baw/community/buzzaboutwireless/phones-and-devices/lg/lg_optimus_g/blog/2013/03/07/lg-optimus-g-software-updates))

### Micromax

#### A110 Canvas 2

- Official: *2013-March* ([confirmed](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/micromax-a110-canvas-2-to-get-android-jelly-bean-update-339933))

### Motorola

#### DROID 4

- Released to Verizon customers March 19, 2013 ([confirmed](http://www.phonescoop.com/articles/article.php?a=12104))

#### DROID BIONIC

- Official: 2013-04-16 ([confirmed](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949#gs=eyJndWlkZUlEIjoxOTQ5LCJxdWVzdGlvbklEIjo2LCJyZXNwb25zZUlEIjoyNSwiZ3VpZGVTZXNzaW9uIjoiT1k2Nm9TbmwiLCJzZXNzaW9uSUQiOiJjYXhBalNubCJ9))

#### DROID RAZR

- Official: 2012-03-07 ([confirmed](http://www.motorola.com/blog/2013/03/07/droid-razr-droid-razr-maxx-by-motorola-receives-android-4-1-jelly-bean/))

#### DROID RAZR HD

- Official: 2012-12 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/jelly-bean-lands-on-verizon-droid-razr-hd-and-razr-maxx-hd-next-week-20121130/))

#### DROID RAZR MAXX

- Official: 2012-03-07 ([confirmed](http://www.motorola.com/blog/2013/03/07/droid-razr-droid-razr-maxx-by-motorola-receives-android-4-1-jelly-bean/))

#### RAZR MAXX HD

- Official: 2012-12 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/jelly-bean-lands-on-verizon-droid-razr-hd-and-razr-maxx-hd-next-week-20121130/))

### Pantech

#### Discover

- Official: 2013-07-31 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/pantech-discover-getting-android-4-1-2-jelly-bean-20130731/))

### Samsung

#### Epic 4G Touch

- Official (via Samsung Kies): *2013-03-28* ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/25277/android-4-1-jelly-bean-now-available-for-the-sprint-epic-4g-touch/))

#### Galaxy Ace 2

- available: 2013-05-15 ([SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/2013/05/15/samsung-start-android-4-1-2-jelly-bean-updates-galaxy-ace-2-gt-i8160p/))

#### Galaxy Nexus

- HSPA+

  - yakju, takju

    - Official: 10-July-2012 ([officially confirmed](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112773496741623034196/posts/QLETQNekJ6D))
    - Unofficial: 28-June-2012 [RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/28494-rom41-jelly-belly-w-awesomebeats%E2%84%A2-nothin-but-butter/), [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1737849)
  - yakjuxw, yakjukr etc...

    - Official: *Unknown*
    - Unofficial: 30-June-2012 [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=28178320&postcount=2)
- CDMA

  - Sprint:

    - Official: 2012-09-06 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/09/06/sprint-galaxy-nexus-set-to-receive-jelly-bean-update-today-where-you-at-verizon/))
    - Unofficial: 2012-06-28 [ACSyndicate](http://forums.acsyndicate.net/showthread.php?5535-ACS-ROM-4-1-JRN84D-Galaxy-Nexus-Jellin-RC_1&fb_action_ids=253224554793555&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582)
  - Verizon Wireless:

    - Official: 2012-09-21 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/21/verizon-finally-pushing-jelly-bean-jro03o-to-the-samsung-galaxy-nexus/))
    - Unofficial: 28-June-2012 RootzWiki ([ROM 1](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/28473-rom-jds-jellybean-v21-everything-workswifi-fixed/), [ROM 2](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/28486-vicious-toro-jellybean-fully-100-fucntional-deodexed-calls-wifi-data-3g-4g-etc-build-is-now-up/))

#### Galaxy Note N7000

- Official: *Unknown date*
- Unofficial: [2012-08-10](http://get.cm/?device=n7000)

#### Galaxy S II

- Official (Sweden, Norway and Denmark): November 2012 ([facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/samsungsverige/app_208195102528120) via [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/galaxy_s_ii_to_taste_jelly_bean_in_november_s_iii_in_october-news-4793.php))

#### Galaxy S III

- Official (Verizon Wireless) 15-Dec-2012 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii-jelly-bean-update-approved-coming-this-weekend-20121212/))
- "[Confirmed](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2012/08/android-4-1-jelly-bean-confirmed-for-international-samsung-galaxy-s3-models-next-week/)" 29-August-2012 (international models specifically)
- Official (Sweden, Norway and Denmark): October 2012 ([facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/samsungsverige/app_208195102528120) via [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/galaxy_s_ii_to_taste_jelly_bean_in_november_s_iii_in_october-news-4793.php))
- Official (Bell, Rogers, Sasktel, Telus, and associated brands in Canada): December 3, 2012 ([twitter post](https://twitter.com/SamsungMobileCA/status/273608404155629568))
- Official (Mobilicity, Vidéotron and Wind Mobile in Canada) - December 14, 2012 ([twitter post](https://twitter.com/SamsungMobileCA/status/279277483893874689))

#### Galaxy Stellar

- Official: March 2, 2013 ([source](http://androidspin.com/2013/03/02/verizon-samsung-galaxy-stellar-receiving-jellybean-update/))

### Sony

#### 2011 line up (Xperia Arc S, Ray, Mini (pro), Neo (V), ...)

- Declined by Sony UK for the top model Arc S ([source](http://www.androiduknewsetc.com/2012/07/no-jelly-bean-for-the-arc-s-or-other-2011-xperia-phones/))

#### Xperia T, TX, V

- Official:Feb-March 2013 ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2012/12/17/update-on-sony-software-upgrades-including-uplift-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-for-2012-xperia-smartphones/))

#### Xperia P, J, Go)

- Official: End of March 2013 ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2012/12/17/update-on-sony-software-upgrades-including-uplift-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-for-2012-xperia-smartphones/))

#### Xperia S, SL, ion, acro S

- Official:After March 2013 ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2012/12/17/update-on-sony-software-upgrades-including-uplift-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-for-2012-xperia-smartphones/))

#### Xperia U, Miro, Tipo, Sola

- Official: Declined ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2012/12/17/update-on-sony-software-upgrades-including-uplift-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-for-2012-xperia-smartphones/))

#### Xperia TL

- Official: 1-Mar-2013 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/jelly-bean-now-available-for-att-sony-xperia-tl-users-20130312/))

## **Tablets**

### Acer

#### Iconia Tab A500

- Unofficial: 30-Jun-2012 ([confirmed](http://thedroidguy.com/2012/06/iconia-tab-a500-by-acer-gets-unofficial-android-4-1-build/))

### ASUS

#### Transformer TF101 + SL101

- Official: *unknown date* ([confirmed](http://omgdroid.com/asus-confirms-original-transformer-tf101-and-slider-sl1-will-get-updated-to-jelly-bean/))

#### Transformer TF201 + TF300T + TF700T

- Official, *unknown date* ([source](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tabletsmagazine.nl%2F2012%2F07%2Fasus-transformer-prime-pad-300-en-pad-infinity-krijgen-android-4-1-jelly-bean-update%2F))  ([source, English](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29067489&postcount=9))

#### Transformer Pad TF300

- Official: 18-August-2012 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/08/18/jelly-bean-rolling-out-to-asus-transformer-pad-tf300/))

### Lenovo

#### Thinkpad Tablet

- Official: Never ([staff post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/Thinkpad_slate/message-id/16449/print-single-message/true/page/1))

### Motorola

#### Xoom

- Official (Wi-Fi variant): 23-July-2012 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/case-you-needed-confirmation-it-jelly-bean-will-be-arriving-xoom-wifi))
- Official (3G/LTE variant): Q4 2012 ([Motorola blog post](https://forums.motorola.com/pages/00add97d6c))

Comment: Why the rollback? There are separate entries for US operators, I thought it would be relevant to have separate entries for european users also.

Comment: I rolled it back because the edit summary said it was adding a separate Verizon entry and there already _is_ one. Go ahead and restore the change. Note, though, that most "normal" users aren't going to know what build codes are or what they mean.

Comment: That's true, exactly why I wrote and answered [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26157) question. And if one goes searching for information on how to upgrade before OTA, one is bound to bump into the matter.