# How to upgrade to Jelly Bean (Android 4.1) for an ASUS Transformer TF300 or TF201?

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean)

If the Android device is a tablet but not a phone -- such as for ASUS Tranformer TF300 -- then how can the device be upgraded to Android 4.1?

Comment: the question deserves a `-2` vote?

Answer (score 6):

The same way as the phone would be: you have to wait for your manufacturer (in this case ASUS) releases an OTA update.

Android JellyBean hasn't been released yet - source and updates for Google Nexus devices will be released on July 15th, so update for your tablet probably wont be available for at least a month.

Of course the other option is rooting and installing a 3rd party image, **however I strongly advise against it unless you know what you are doing**. And even those images wont be available until Google releases the source on July 15th.