# How to put android 4.1 (jelly bean) on nook color

Tags: nook-color, 4.1-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean)

I am running CM9, just so you know that it's been flashed before.
My question has 2 parts:

1. Will the nexus 7 rom work (https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi)
2. If not, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4):

> Will the nexus 7 rom work (https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi)

No.

> If not, how can I make it work?

This is quite honestly too extensive to cover in one Stack Exchange answer, and is arguably outside of the scope of our site anyway. Suffice it to say, you'd probably need to find or write driver implementations for all of the hardware, get them into a JB compatible kernel, and then put together a system image that actually boots with all of the above. Any driver/firmware code that is closed source would possibly have to be reverse-engineered.  It's not a particularly trivial task.

Comment: Would I be able to  use the CM7 or 9 kernel for nook color together with the nexus 7 image?

Comment: @m12: I have no idea. It depends on whether or not significant necessary changes have been made at the kernel level in Jelly Bean. It's possible, but if it actually runs it may not run well at all. You'd also likely have to still make some sizeable changes to the Nexus 7 image to even get it booting. If it was as easy as just dropping in the NC kernel then wouldn't you assume that there would be JB ROMs released already?

Comment: Probably, but its worth a try, I'll report here with whether it works.