# Installing ICS or JellyBeans on Sony Xperia U

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

I'm considering getting an Android mobile phone and Sony Xperia U fits my needs.
However, it comes with Sony TimeScape UI (which I don't like) and an old Android version.

Is it possible to install Android 4.0+ on Sony Xperia U? If yes, would you please tell me how?

*I'm new to Android world and know nothing :)*

Comment: Have you looked at http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/267 or http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14766/267 to see if there's an official version or if anyone has built a custom ROM?

Comment: Even of Sony is going to release an Update to ICS or JB, it will be packed with Timescape UI which I don't want to use. I'm looking to install plain Vanilla Android 4.0> on Xperia U