# How to find what model of Galaxy Nexus I have?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

I cannot determine what version of the Google Nexus I have. I purchased the phone from the Google Play store in 2012. In the phone "settings" menu, the model says "Galaxy Nexus" and the Android Version is 4.3. It lists the serial number but appears to be useless when trying to look up on Samsung support site.

How do I know if I have Nexus 4, Nexus 7, etc? I want to look up the exact hardware specifications for this exact phone. I tried searching the Samsung website by the IMEI but nothing could be found. The phone was manufactured by Samsung (SAMSUNG logo on the back of the phone). The Google Play store purchase receipt just says "Galaxy Nexus HSPA+".

Is there some other way I can find the exact information for this phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out the variant of my Galaxy Nexus?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26157/how-to-find-out-the-variant-of-my-galaxy-nexus)

Answer (score 2):

"Galaxy Nexus" is the full name of your model. The Nexus 4, Nexus 7, etc are all different models entirely. The only portion of the naming convention that is shared is **Nexus**; the "Galaxy" moniker is one that Samsung likes to use for its phones, and thus they applied it to one of the Nexus phones that they produced. If you were to refer to the line of devices as a group, you would therefore call them *Nexus devices*, not *Galaxy Nexus devices*, as the Galaxy Nexus is simply one model in the Nexus line.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus#Devices) has a list of all Nexus devices released to date, along with links to pages specific to those devices. As you can see, "Galaxy Nexus" is listed between its predecessor (the Nexus S) and its successor (the Nexus 4). The HSPA+ variant sold on Google Play was given the codename "maguro". There are also [other variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus#Variants) of the Galaxy Nexus for other carriers, so you can generally know which variant you have based on which carrier you use it with (or purchased it from).