# Jelly Bean update for an Unlocked AT&T HTC One X?

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean)

Now that the Jelly Bean update for the One X has been made official for atleast the GLobal version: http://www.engadget.com/2012/10/02/htc-jelly-bean-one-series/

Would I be able to update an Unlocked "AT&T" HTC One X when the update is releasaed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the Global version of 4.1 firmware on the AT&T-branded One X model will most likely be impossible due to the [hardware differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_One_X#One_X_.28North_America.29) between the different variants of this handset:

> *[AT&T variant]* is 0.4mm longer than the international model, and
>   features a 1.5 GHz dual-core Qualcomm Snapdragon S4 (MSM8960) SoC with
>   an integrated on-die LTE (4G) modem instead of the Nvidia Tegra 3 *[found on the international model]* 
>   which requires an external modem and is LTE-incompatible, and 16 GB of
>   internal storage instead of 32 GB.

You will either have to wait for HTC and AT&T to release an official version of Jelly Bean for your model, or take the plunge and root, bootloader unlock, and flash a custom ROM on your own if you want 4.1 sooner.  Instructions for doing so can be found at [XDA-developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1671237).