# When will my device get the Android 4.2 update (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, android-versions

Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) was officially announced on October 29, 2012.

(You can review [the high level changes in Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#android-42) at the official Android Developer's site.)

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 4.2, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.3 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49832/1465)
- [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684/1465)

Comment: Richard, I think we might be better served by incorporating 4.2 into [the existing 4.1 post](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/1465) since they share the name, like we did with Honeycomb 3.0/3.1/3.2.  What do you think?

Comment: @MatthewRead I think that sounds appropriate to me.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I'm somewhat inclined to disagree simply because of the sheer number of devices. With 3.x updates it was a fairly confined set of tablets that needed to be covered (since literally *nothing* else was going to get it). I could see it making sense to contain all of the info in one place, however, since it is still Jelly Bean and contains not-as-gigantic changes as a release with a new name usually does. If we do merge then I think we should have two answers: one for 4.1 and one for 4.2, and the question can link down to each of them to make it easier on readers.

Comment: ...so basically, either one seems like it makes sense. I think we either need to break the 4.1/4.2 stuff into two questions or two answers, but either one seems pretty reasonable. (/cc @BryanDenny)

Comment: @MatthewRead I agree with eldarerathis. 3.x updates concerned a limited number of devices compared to 4.2.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm fine with leaving this as-is then :)

Comment: The [AOKP project](http://aokp.co/index.php/news) already start to develop a ROM to 4.2.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it's available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-wh)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### HTC

- **One (Developer Edition)**: skipping to 4.3 ([source](http://androidspin.com/2013/08/19/htc-one-developer-edition-will-skip-android-4-2-2-and-go-straight-to-android-4-3/))
- **One S**: *Never* ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2013/07/02/htc-says-no-further-updates-for-htc-one-s/))
- **One X**: 2013-06 ([rumor](http://www.cultofandroid.com/25410/htc-one-x-to-get-android-4-2-2-jelly-bean-with-sense-5-around-june-rumor/))
- **One X+**: 2013-08-12 Taiwan ([confirmed](http://htcsource.com/2013/08/htc-one-x-android-4-2-2-update-with-sense-5-now-available-in-taiwan/))

### Samsung

- **Galaxy Nexus**: *Released* - November 13th, 2012

  - Bell Canada: 2013-03-08 ([confirmed](http://mobilesyrup.com/2013/03/07/bell-samsung-galaxy-nexus-receiving-os-4-2-upgrade-on-march-8th/))
  - Verizon: 2013-03-19 ([official](http://news.verizonwireless.com/news/2013/03/galaxy-nexus-jelly-bean.html))
- **Nexus S**: Never ([source](http://www.tapscape.com/google-nexus-s-and-motorola-xoom-wont-be-getting-android-4-2/)). There's an [unofficial release](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/android-4-2-makes-its-way-to-the-nexus-s/), see also [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992411).

### Sony

- **Xperia Z**: 2013-July ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2013/07/25/on-android-jelly-bean-4-3/))
- **Xperia ZL**: 2013-July ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2013/07/25/on-android-jelly-bean-4-3/))
- **Xperia ZR**: 2013-August ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2013/07/25/on-android-jelly-bean-4-3/))

## Tablets

### Asus

- **Nexus 7**: *Released* - November 13, 2012
- **Transformer Infinity** - April 3, 2013 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/04/03/asus-announces-android-4-2-update-for-transformer-infinity-rolls-out-today/))
- **Transformer Pad TF300**: *Released* - March 3, 2013 ([source](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/03/03/asus-makes-the-transformer-pad-tf300-the-first-non-nexus-to-receive-android-4-2-update/))

### Motorola

- **Xoom**: *Never* ([source](http://www.tapscape.com/google-nexus-s-and-motorola-xoom-wont-be-getting-android-4-2/))

### Samsung

- **Galaxy Note 8.0**

  - Wi-Fi only: 2013-10-07 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/42778/samsung-pushing-out-android-4-2-2-for-wi-fi-galaxy-note-8-0/))
- **Galaxy Tab 2 7.0**: 2013-08-13 UK ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/39292/samsung-rolls-out-android-4-2-2-for-the-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-in-the-u-k/))
- **Galaxy Tab 2 10.1**: 2013-09-23 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/41995/samsung-pushing-out-android-4-2-2-for-galaxy-tab-2/))

### Sony

- **Xperia Tablet Z**: 2013-August ([confirmed](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2013/07/25/on-android-jelly-bean-4-3/))

## Other

### GoogleTV

- **LG Google TV**: 2013-10-14 ([source](http://androidcommunity.com/lg-google-tv-reportedly-getting-update-to-android-4-2-2-this-monday-20131010/))
- All ARM-based models - 2013-05-16 ([source](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleTVDevelopers/posts/X5rmq6Yu8xG), [source2](http://gigaom.com/2013/05/15/google-tv-android-jelly-bean-update/))
- All 1st gen Intel-based models (e.g. Logitech Revue) - *Never*