# Is there a JellyBean ROM for Xoom2 ME?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, motorola-xoom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

As the question's title says, I'm trying to find an upgrade ROM for my Motorola Xoom 2 ME WiFi-only (MZ607). At CyanogenMod, I could find a ROM for Xoom, but not for Xoom 2.

Does anyone have an idea where could I find one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for stock ROM? Or CyanogenMod ROM?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32589/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-2-update-jelly-bean

Comment: @geff_chang, There's no Jelly Bean stock ROM (at least not as of yet or that I could find) for my tablet. I was looking for a CyanogenMod ROM of something similar.