# How to create multiple user accounts with password for each in galaxy note 800 with Android 4.0.1?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, password, multi-user, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have recently bought Samsung galaxy note 800 (10.1") which has android 4.0.1
How to create multiple user account accounts with passwords on it?

Answer (score 3):

Multi-User was added with Android 4.2 -- you're running 4.0, so there's no *native* way to go multi-user without upgrading your system.

If you have your device rooted, you might want to take a look at [SwitchMe Multiple Accounts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme), which works with Android 2.1 and up. With Android 4.1, you could make use of the [User Management](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appaholics.um) app. Both would enable you to have a multi-user feature on your device.

Comment: there's no native way to go multi-user without upgrading your system. How to upgrade my system? Which version? - to get native multiple user support.

Comment: As I wrote: for native support, you'll need at least Android 4.2. How to upgrade your system is a separate question, where you might want to check [When will my device get the Android 4.2 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32589/16575), or [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)