# When will my device get the Android 4.3 update (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: updates, 4.3-jelly-bean, android-versions

Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) was officially announced on July 24, 2013.

(You can review [the high level changes in Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#android-43) at the official Android Developer's site or the [announcement on the official Android blog](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2013/07/introducing-android-43-sweeter-jelly.html).)

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 4.3, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 4.2 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32589)
- [When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56112)
- [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684/1465)

Comment: Steve Kondik of CyanogenMod announced a while ago on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/100275307499530023476/posts/3jpUbS59qZ1), CM-10.2 will be in the pipeline, just don't ask for *ETA* 's :)

Comment: And for those unfamiliar, CM-10.2 will be based on Jelly Bean 4.3 source code. I eagerly anticipate its arrival!

Comment: I guess this question tells us [when Unicorns were photographed in the SE headquarters](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.70879,-74.006702,3a,75y,186.48h,77.6t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sMM_H8jYJEgIAAAQIt-NMlw!2e0!3e2)... ;-)

Comment: (@AlE, I noticed you changed your display name on many, or all, sites. If you want me to remove my above comment, then just shout!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### HTC

- **EVO 4G LTE**: end of 2013 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-lte-set-receive-android-43-and-sense-5-end-year))
- **One**

  - Google Play Edition: 2013-08-01 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/02/android-4-3-update-rolling-out-to-google-play-edition-samsung-galaxy-s4-and-htc-one/))
  - With HTC Sense: 2013-09-27 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2013/09/uncategorized/htc-android-4-3-rollout-for-htc-one-to-commence-this-week/))
- **One (Developer Edition)**: 2013-09-27 ([source](http://androidandme.com/2013/09/uncategorized/htc-android-4-3-rollout-for-htc-one-to-commence-this-week/))
- **One X** and **One X+**: *Never* ([source](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/01/htc-one-x-and-one-x-will-not-receive-kitkat-stuck-on-android-4-2-forever/))

### LG

- **Nexus 4**: 2013-07-24 ([announced](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/24/4550234/android-4-3-announcement))

### Samsung

- **Galaxy Nexus**:

  - GSM/HSPA+: 2013-07-24 ([announced](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/24/4550234/android-4-3-announcement))
  - Sprint: *unknown*
  - Verizon:

    - Official: *unknown*
    - Unofficial: 2013-07-24: ([RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/36706-romaosp4372413-shiny-ota-like-stock-android-43-jss15j-no-bugs/))
- **Galaxy Note II**: December 2013 ([rumor](http://www.cultofandroid.com/42298/samsung-prepares-android-4-3-updates-for-galaxy-s4-galaxy-s-iii-galaxy-note-ii/))
- **Galaxy S 3**: October 2013 ([source](http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/04/android-4-3-arriving-for-galaxy-s-3-and-galaxy-s-4-in-october/))
- **Galaxy S 4**

  - Google Play Edition: 2013-08-02 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/02/android-4-3-update-rolling-out-to-google-play-edition-samsung-galaxy-s4-and-htc-one/))
  - With Touchwiz: 2013-10-17 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2013/10/17/samsung-galaxy-s4-officially-scores-android-4-3/))
- **Nexus S**

  - Unofficial: 2013-07-27: ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2013/07/28/fancy-android-4-3-on-your-nexus-s/) - [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2380527))

### Sony

- **Xperia SP**: beginning 2014-Jan ([confirmed](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/software/phones/xperia-sp/))
- **Xperia T**: beginning 2013-Dec ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia TX**: beginning 2013-Dec ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia V**: beginning 2013-Dec ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia Z**: 2013-12-23 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia Z Ultra**: 2013-12-16 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia Z1**: 2013-12-16 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia ZL**: 2013-12-23 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))
- **Xperia ZR**: 2013-12-23 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))

## Tablets

### Asus

- **Nexus 7** (2012): 2013-07-24 ([announced](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/24/4550234/android-4-3-announcement))

### Samsung

- **Nexus 10**: 2013-07-24 ([announced](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/24/4550234/android-4-3-announcement))

### Sony

- **Xperia Tablet Z**: 2013-12-23 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/07/sony-xperia-kitkat-update/))

## Other

### GoogleTV

- All models - *Unknown*

### Nvidia Shield

- 2013-10-28 - ([confirmed](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2426399,00.asp))

Comment: A note on dates: Dates listed are generally when the update is announced to be available. However, due to phased rollouts you may not see the actual update for some time.