# Can I Upgrade My Samsung Tablet From Ice Cream Sandwich To Jelly Bean & How ?

Tags: tablet, samsung

I bought a Samsung tablet with Ice cream sandwich installed, can I upgrade it to Jelly Bean & how ? Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) / [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575/16575) / [When will my device get the Android 4.2 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32589/16575) / [When will my device get the Android 4.3 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49832/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Which model?

Try checking from the

Setting Menu > About Device (or your Tablet) > System Updates.

You will be prompted if there is a firmware update.

Hoped it helps.