# When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, android-versions

Android 5.0 (Lollipop) was officially announced on October 15th, 2014.

You can review the high-level changes at the [Android website](http://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/) and the announcement on the official [Android blog](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-be-together-not-same.html).

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Android 5.0, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 4.4 update (KitKat)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56112)
- [When will my device get the Android 5.1 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/102043)
- [When will my device get the Android 6.0 update (Marshmallow)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110681)

Comment: Also of note: [Who gets Android Lollipop: The hints, the rumors, and the sure things](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2834616/who-gets-android-lollipop-the-hints-the-rumors-and-the-sure-things.html)

Comment: Also: [Will my device receive Android Lollipop?](http://www.androidauthority.com/which-phones-android-lollipop-540232/)

Comment: Also: [Android 5.0 Lollipop update: which phones will get it and when?](http://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-phone-update-news)

Comment: Note that there are a number of devices that are skipping the 5.0.x release and going straight to 5.1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep devices in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### HTC

- **Butterfly 2**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **Butterfly S**: *"March-May"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **Desire 816**: *"March-April"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **Desire EYE**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One E8**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One E8 Dual SIM**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One Max**: *"March-May"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One Mini**: <strike>*"March-May"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))</strike> [Not receiving update](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/50533/20150505/no-lollipop-update-for-htc-one-mini-and-one-mini-2.htm)
- **One Mini 2**: <strike>*"March-April"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))</strike> [Not receiving update](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/50533/20150505/no-lollipop-update-for-htc-one-mini-and-one-mini-2.htm)
- **One M7**: *"within 90 days"* ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/69786/htc-one-m8-one-m7-get-lollipop-within-90-days/)), *"GPE is late November-December, Sense based devices is January-February"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One M7 Dual SIM**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One M8**: *"within 90 days"* ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/69786/htc-one-m8-one-m7-get-lollipop-within-90-days/)), *"GPE is late November-December, Sense based devices is January-February"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))
- **One M8 Dual SIM**: *"January-March"* ([confirmed](http://llabtoofer.com/2014/10/19/htc-android-5-0-lolipop-update/))

### LG

- **G2**: Will follow the G3 update ([source](https://www.facebook.com/LG/photos/a.154854208092.118128.92760728092/10152414361038093/?type=1&theater))
- **G3**: Q4 2014 ([source](http://androidspin.com/2014/10/25/lg-says-lg-g3-android-lollipop-update-coming-end-2014/), [source2](https://www.facebook.com/LG/photos/a.154854208092.118128.92760728092/10152414361038093/?type=1&theater))
- **Nexus 4**: 2014-11-14 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-be-together-not-same.html), [confirmed](http://www.gsmarena.com/android_50_factory_image_for_nexus_4_is_now_available-news-10217.php))
- **Nexus 5**: 2014-11-12 ([official](https://twitter.com/Android/status/532623587874963456), [confirmed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/other-discussions/nexus-5/f1EOEtihDxI))

  - The Nexus 5 is also one of the two devices for which there is an [official developer preview image](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

### Motorola

- **Droid Maxx**: *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Mini**: *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Droid Ultra**: *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Moto E**: *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Moto G** (1st & 2nd gen): *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))

  - 2nd gen / unlocked: 2014-11-11 ([confirmed](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/11/unlocked-2014-moto-gs-can-download-their-lollipop-update-now/))
- **Moto G with 4G LTE**: *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))
- **Moto X** (1st & 2nd gen): *Yes* ([official](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1949))

  - 2nd gen

    - unlocked: 2014-11-11 ([confirmed](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/11/unlocked-2014-moto-gs-can-download-their-lollipop-update-now/))
    - Verizon: 2014-11-25 ([confirmed](http://www.cultofandroid.com/70477/motorola-brings-android-5-0-lollipop-moto-x-users-verizon/))

### OnePlus

- **One**: *Yes* ([rumor](http://androidandme.com/2014/07/news/oneplus-one-confirmed-to-get-android-l-update/))

### Samsung

- **Galaxy Note 2**: *Never* ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2015/07/06/samsung-galaxy-note-2-s3-no-android-50-lollipop/))
- **Galaxy Note 4**: *Yes* ([source](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_4_and_edge_will_get_android_501_directly-news-10514.php))

  - Exynos variant: 2015-02-11 ([confirmed](http://www.gsmarena.com/exynos_galaxy_note_4_is_getting_lollipop_ota_in_poland-news-11148.php))
- **Galaxy S 3**: *Never* ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2015/07/06/samsung-galaxy-note-2-s3-no-android-50-lollipop/))
- **Galaxy S 4**: *Probably, early 2015* ([rumor](http://www.sammobile.com/2014/11/03/sammobile-confirms-android-5-0-lollipop-for-the-samsung-galaxy-s4/))
- **Galaxy S 5**: December, 2014 ([source](http://androidspin.com/2014/10/25/samsung-galaxy-s5-android-lollipop-update-hit-sometime-december/))

### Sony

- **Xperia Z Series**: *Yes* ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/sony-bring-lollipop-entire-xperia-z-series))
  (Xperia Z, Xperia ZL, Xperia ZR, Xperia Z1, Xperia Z1S, Xperia Z Ultra, Xperia Z1 Compact, Xperia Z2, Xperia Z3, Xperia Z3v, Xperia Z3 Compact)

## Tablets

### Asus

- **Nexus 7** (2012 & 2013): "In the coming weeks" ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2014/10/android-be-together-not-same.html))

  - WiFi versions: 2014-11-12 ([official](https://twitter.com/Android/status/532623587874963456), [confirmed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/other-discussions/nexus-5/f1EOEtihDxI))
  - The Nexus 7 2013 Wi-Fi is also one of the two devices for which there is an [official developer preview image](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

### LG

- **G Pad 8.3**

  - Google Play Edition: 2014-11-29 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2014/11/news/lg-g-pad-8-3-google-play-edition-getting-its-taste-of-lollipop/))

### Nvidia

- **Shield**: 2014-11-18 ([official](http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2014/11/13/sweet-updates-shield-tablet/))
- **Tegra Note 7** (aka Advent Vega Tegra Note 7, Xolo Play Tegra Note 7, eVGA Tegra Note 7, GAZER Tegra Note 7, Gigabyte Tegra Note 7, HP Slate 7 Extreme): *Yes* ([confirmed](http://www.fudzilla.com/home/item/35101-tegra-note-7-is-getting-android-l))

### Samsung

- **Nexus 10**: 2014-11-12 ([official](https://twitter.com/Android/status/532623587874963456), [confirmed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/other-discussions/nexus-5/f1EOEtihDxI))

### Sony

- **Xperia Z Tablet Series**: *Yes* ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/sony-bring-lollipop-entire-xperia-z-series))
  (Xperia Tablet Z, Xperia Z2 Tablet, Xperia Z3 Tablet Compact)

## Other