# On Nexus 4, system still "up to date" with Kit-Kat

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update

I would like to install Lollipop over the air on my Nexus 4. I know that there is a factory image available, but I'd rather avoid install that if I can.

I have a Nexus 4 that has been turned off from mid-September of this year to mid-December. It had a bad charger port.

I had it fixed, charged it, and updated everything. Android updated to version 4.4.4. And that was it. Now, every time I look at System Update it says "Your system is up to date". If I manually check updates, it doesn't change anything.

Did I miss some sort of window for Lollipop? How can I get the over-the-air Lollipop install for my Nexus 4? Or will I need to do a whole system update from a computer and reinstall everything?

Also maybe worthy of note: this phone is not currently connected to a phone carrier. It's just used as a wifi. I do intend to connect it to a phone carrier very soon, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-5-0-update-lollipop)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @RyanConrad. Actually, I'll add something to that effect.

Comment: In that question, the nexus 4 is in that list, you can get the link to the system images from there. From those images, you can download them and manually update the device.

Comment: But updating from a system image is much more complicated than over the air. So I'd rather not do it unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Agreed, it is more complicated than an OTA. Maybe modify your question then to indicate you want to get the OTA, not manually. Otherwise you may end up with just answers saying to get the system image and manually apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Android finally updated. It found the update the instant I tried to connect through my phone service, as opposed to connecting via wifi. The strange thing is that I could not in fact connect via the phone. But apparently, turning on the mobile data switch prompted the message that an update to Lollipop was available, even if there was no mobile data to be used there.