# How Can I Access "Android Lollipop"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, installation, downloading, android-versions

I'm looking to download "Android 5 Lollipop" for my Samsung Galaxy S4 i9505. I want the official "thing". My questions are...

1. Where can I download this?
2. Any methods of installation?
3. Do I need to erase ALL data from my phone?
4. Any other things i should know?

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-5-0-update-lollipop The entry for the SGS4 links to Samsung's Lollipop announcement for that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait. Watch the news. I have been now for a while, it appears to be getting released in some countries, but you will hear about it if you watch/listen.

Answer (score 0):

Best option (only option so far as i know) is Root + safestrap.

Details: Samsung locked their bootloaders - Bootloader access is required to write new operating software (analogous to installing windows)

Safestrap is a way of isolating different Operrating software; and running it without unlocking.

So: If you want Lollipop You will have to Root your phone, install SafeStrap, and then acquire a LP Rom.

Google search term: Root Safestrap Galaxy S4 *current version here*
PS: Always backup your data before starting this process.
Your unsaved text messages will be lost.

Comment: Do you have any idea if samsung will release there version of lollipop out as a normal simple update?

Comment: They will. Yes. But frankly - Samsung software is bad. Honestly; I fix them all the time and the software is garbage.