# When will my device get the Android 5.1 update (Lollipop)?

Tags: updates, 5.1-lollipop, android-versions

Android 5.1 (Lollipop) was officially announced on March 9th, 2015.

You can review the high-level changes at the announcement on the official [Android blog](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html).

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away and others won't get it at all. Each manufacturer and carrier often choose to add their custom modifications which tend to delay the official release.

When will each device get Android 5.1, either officially or unofficially, if ever?

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684)
- [When will my device get the Android 6.0 update (Marshmallow)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110681)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep devices in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### HTC

- **One M9**: 2015-07 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2015/07/03/htc-one-m9-developer-edition-android-51-lollipop-update/))

### LG

- **Nexus 4**: 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))
- **Nexus 5**: 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))

### Motorola

- **DROID Turbo**: 2015-07-01 ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2015/07/01/android-5-1-lollipop-update-for-droid-turbo-now-live/))
- **Nexus 6**: 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))

### OnePlus

### Samsung

- **Galaxy S II**: unofficial (Cyanogenmod)  ([via](http://androidcommunity.com/classic-devices-get-android-5-1-motorola-xoom-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-20150706/) | [Cyanogenmod Download](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i9100&type=nightly))

### Sony

## Tablets

### Asus

- **Nexus 7** (2012 & 2013): 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))

### HTC

- **Nexus 6**: 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))

### LG

### Motorola

- **Xoom**: unofficial (OmniROM) ([via](http://androidcommunity.com/classic-devices-get-android-5-1-motorola-xoom-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-20150706/) | [Official XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/motorola-xoom/development/rom-omnirom-wingray-bigpart-alpha-t3147007))

### Nvidia

- **Shield Tablet (WiFi and LTE)**: 2015-05-22 ([Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/22/shield-tablet-update-3-0-android-5-1-is-rolling-out-to-the-wi-fi-version-right-now/))

### Samsung

- **Nexus 10**: 2015-03-09 ([official](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-51-unwrapping-new-lollipop.html))

### Sony

## Other

Answer (score 0):

**Nexus 4   Android 5.1.1
Nexus 5     Android 5.1.1
Nexus 6     Android 5.1.1
Nexus 7     Android 5.1.1
Nexus 9     Android 5.1.1
Nexus 10    Android 5.1.1
Samsung Galaxy S6   Android 5.1.1
Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge  Android 5.1.1
Samsung Galaxy Note Edge    Android 5.1.1
LG G2   Android 5.1
LG G2 Mini  Android 5.1
LG G3   Android 5.1
LG G Flex 2     Android 5.1.1
Sony Xperia Z series    Android 5.1
Sony Xperia Z3  Android 5.1.1
Xperia M2   Android 5.1
Xperia M2 Aqua  Android 5.1
Huawei Ascend Mate 7    Android 5.1
MOTO X (1st Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO X (2nd Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO G (1st Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO G (2nd Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO E (1st Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO E (2nd Gen)    Android 5.1
MOTO Droid Turbo    Android 5.1
HTC One M7          Android 5.1
HTC One M8          Android 5.1
HTC One M9          Android 5.1
HTC One Max         Android 5.1**

And if your device is not among the listed devices then you need to wait for an update and most of the mobiles wont get updated even though you wait.
if you are an android enthusiast then its better to switch on to latest devices.