# Android 5.1 on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.1-lollipop

I have upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S4 to Android 5.0.1. It is full of bugs, but I don't wont to downgrade to Kitkat.

I have heard that Android 5.1 is available. Is it possible to get it for my S4?

Comment: Please see: [When will my device get the Android 5.1 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102043/16575)

Answer (score 0):

We are just ***Android Users***, it means, you need to follow the Sites or below link for find any update you need it :

[**SamMobile - Firmware Search**](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)

also, if you need `5.1.0` you can use custom roms if this version availabe for your phone.

good day.