# When will my device get the Android 8.0 update (Oreo)?

Tags: updates, android-versions, 8.0-oreo

Android Oreo [was officially released on August 21, 2017](https://www.blog.google/products/android/android-oreo-superpowers-coming-device-near-you/).  It adds features such as picture-in-picture and AutoFill.

You can review the high-level changes at [the Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/index.html).

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away, even at release; others won't get it at all. Manufacturers and carriers often choose to add their own custom modifications, which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Oreo, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 6.0 update (Marshmallow)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110681/30530)
- [When will my device get the Android 7.0 update (Nougat)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/139232/30530)
- [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) (with links to all other versions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices.

If you have an update please edit this wiki [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/181739/edit), but make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep devices in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and **link to the source**
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

## Phones

### Asus

- **ZenPhone 3**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/zenfone-3-will-eventually-get-android-o-but-you-dont-have-to-wait-18495701/)
- **ZenPhone AR**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)

### Blackberry

- **KEYone**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/21/so-when-will-your-device-actually-get-android-oreo/)

### Google

- **Pixel**: 2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)
- **Pixel XL**: 2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)

### HTC

- **U Play**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **U Ultra**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **U11**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/21/so-when-will-your-device-actually-get-android-oreo/)

### Huawei

- **Honor 9:** 2017-10-30 [confirmed](http://teamdroids.com/huawei-honor-9-android-8-0-oreo-update/)
- **Nexus 6P**: 2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)

### LG

- **G6**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Nexus 5X**: 2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)
- **Q6**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)

### Motorola

- **Moto G5**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto G5 Plus**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto G5S**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto G5S Plus**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z Droid**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z Force Droid**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z2 Force**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z Play**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)
- **Moto Z2 Play**: *TBD* [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/09/14/motorola-reveals-total-10-moto-z-moto-g-devices-will-get-android-oreo-g4-series-excluded/)

### Nokia

- **Nokia 3**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Nokia 5**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Nokia 6**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Nokia 8**: *TBD* [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/) [pushed](http://www.techradar.com/news/nokia-8-just-got-updated-to-android-oreo-adding-speed-and-features)

### OnePlus

- **OnePlus 3**: [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/oneplus-3-3ts-final-update-will-be-android-o-12494935/) [pushed](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/oneplus-3-3t-android-8-0-oreo-based-update-now-rolling-out-1777650)
- **OnePlus 3T**: [confirmed](https://www.slashgear.com/oneplus-3-3ts-final-update-will-be-android-o-12494935/) [pushed](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/oneplus-3-3t-android-8-0-oreo-based-update-now-rolling-out-1777650)
- **OnePlus 5**: [confirmed](https://www.androidcentral.com/oreo-coming-oneplus-3-3t-5-5t-you-impatient-people), [unofficial on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/development/rom-nitrogen-os-cheeseburger-t3684946)

### Samsung

- **Galaxy A3 (2016)**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy A3 (2017)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy A5 (2016)**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy A5 (2017)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy A7 (2016)**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy A7 (2017)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy C7 Pro**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy C9 Pro**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J1 variants**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J2 (2016)**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J3 (2016)**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J5 (2017)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J7 (2017)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy J7 Prime (OnNxt)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy Note 5**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy Note 8**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy Note FE**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S6 series**: *never* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S7**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S7 Active**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S7 edge**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S8**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy S8+**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)
- **Galaxy Tab S3**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/will-my-phone-get-the-android-oreo-update-22496216/)

### Sony

- **Sony Xperia XZ Premium (G 8141, G 8142)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia XZS (G 8231, G 8232)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia XA 1 (G 3121, G 3123, G 3125, G 3116, G 3123)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia L1 (G3311, G3312, G3313)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia X Compact**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia XZ (F 8331, F 8332)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia X Performance**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia X (F 5121, F 5122)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)
- **Sony Xperia XA 1 Ultra (G 3221, G 3212, G 3223, G 3226)**: *TBD* [rumor](https://www.slashgear.com/sony-xperia-android-o-update-whos-in-and-whos-not-04494051/)

## Tablets

### Asus

### HTC

### Samsung

## Other

- **Nexus Player**: 2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)
- **Pixel C**:  2017-08-21 [confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/21/android-8-0-oreo-system-images-live-pixel-pixel-xl-nexus-5x-nexus-6p-pixel-c-nexus-player/)
- **Smartron SRT Phone**: 2017-07-10 [confirmed](https://newsnexa.com/tech/smartron-srt-android-8-0-update-android-o/)

Comment: How bout Lenovo phones?