# When will my device get the Android 7.0 update (Nougat)?

Tags: updates, android-versions, 7.0-nougat

Android Nougat [was officially released on August 22, 2016](https://android.googleblog.com/2016/08/android-70-nougat-more-powerful-os-made.html).  It adds features such as multi-window support.

You can review the high-level changes at [the Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/index.html).

Of course, not all devices will get this update right away, even at release; others won't get it at all. Manufacturers and carriers often choose to add their own custom modifications, which tend to delay the official release.

**When will each device get Nougat, either officially or unofficially, if ever?**

See also:

- [When will my device get the Android 5.1 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/102043)
- [When will my device get the Android 6.0 update (Marshmallow)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110681)
- [When will my device get the Android 8.0 update (Oreo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/181738)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep devices in alphabetical order, listing the manufacturer and model.
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored, and **link to the source**.
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

---

## Phones

#### Huawei

- **Nexus 6P**:  2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))
- **Mate 8**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))
- **P9**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))
- **P9 Plus**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))
- **P9 Lite**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))
- **Nova**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))
- **Nova Plus**: *Q1 2017* ([source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/01/huawei-announced-phones-will-updated-nougat/))

#### HTC

- **10** - *H1 2017* (depending on regional variant) - ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/02/23/android-7-0-nougat-ota-rolling-htc-10-10-lifestyle-one-m9-europe/))
- **One A9** - *H1 2017* (depending on regional variant) - ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/02/15/sprints-htc-one-a9-gets-its-nougat-ota-update/))
- **One M9** - *H1 2017* (depending on regional variant) - ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/02/23/android-7-0-nougat-ota-rolling-htc-10-10-lifestyle-one-m9-europe/))

#### LG

- **Nexus 5**:  *Never* ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))
- **Nexus 5X**:  2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))

#### Motorola

- **Nexus 6**:  2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))
- **Moto Z**: *by the end of 2016* ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/27/moto-z-moto-g4-nougat-update-release-date-q4/))
- **Moto Z Force**: *by the end of 2016* ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/27/moto-z-moto-g4-nougat-update-release-date-q4/))
- **Moto Z Play**: *by the end of 2016* ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/27/moto-z-moto-g4-nougat-update-release-date-q4/))
- **Moto G4**: *by the end of 2016* ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/27/moto-z-moto-g4-nougat-update-release-date-q4/))
- **Moto G4 Plus**: *by the end of 2016* ([confirmed](http://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/27/moto-z-moto-g4-nougat-update-release-date-q4/))
- **Moto X Pure Edition (3rd Gen)**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))
- **Moto X Style**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))
- **Moto X Play**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))
- **Moto X Force**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))
- **Droid Turbo 2**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))
- **Droid Maxx 2**: *announced* ([source](http://motorola-blog.blogspot.in/2016/10/n-is-for-nougat-android-70-is-coming-to.html))

#### Wileyfox

- According to Wileyfox, ALL of their devices will be updated to 7.1.1 nougat. At time of writing (2017-05-02), the rollout is well underway. ([source](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/amp.androidcentral.com/wileyfox-commits-bringing-nougat-its-entire-portfolio-phones))

#### OnePlus

None yet.

#### Samsung

None yet.

#### Sony

- **Xperia Z3+**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia Z5**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia Z5 Compact**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia Z5 Premium**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia X**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia XA**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia XA Ultra**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))
- **Xperia X Performance**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))

---

## Tablets

#### Asus

- **Nexus 7 (2013)**: *Never* ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))

#### HTC

- **Nexus 9**: 2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))

#### Sony

- **Xperia Z4 tablet**: *announced* ([source](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2016/08/23/sony-xperia-and-android-7-0-nougat/))

#### Other

- **Nexus Player**: 2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))
- **Pixel C**:  2016-08-22 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/08/22/android-7-0-nougat-rolling-nexus-devices-starting-today/))