# How long do Nexus devices get updates?

Tags: updates, google

It's been almost 1/2 a year since the launch of the nexus 2015, and a new one is coming. I want to know how often do android phones get supported with software updates until it becomes obsolete. It will ultimately decided if I should wait for this years model or buy last year's.

What version of Android did each phone in the Nexus line-up stop receiving updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all the info, ordered by release date:

**`Device              Launch Version              Final Version         Lifespan`**

```
Nexus One           2.1   Eclair                2.3   Gingerbread     1y  1m
Nexus S             2.3.6 Gingerbread           4.1.2 Jelly Bean      0y  8m
Galaxy Nexus        4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich    4.3   Jelly Bean      1y  7m
Nexus 4             4.2.2 Jelly Bean            5.1.1 Lollipop        2y 6m
Nexus 7 (2012)      4.1.2 Jelly Bean            5.1.1 Lollipop        2y 8m
Nexus 10            4.2.2 Jelly Bean            5.1.1 Lollipop        2y 4m
Nexus 7 (2013)      4.3   Jelly Bean            current*              N/A: Launched 2013-07
Nexus 5             4.4   Kit Kat               current*              N/A: Launched 2013-10
Nexus 6             5.0   Lollipop              current*              N/A: Launched 2014-11
Nexus 9             5.0   Lollipop              current*              N/A: Launched 2014-11
Nexus Player        5.0   Lollipop              current*              N/A: Launched 2014-11
Nexus 5X            6.0.0 Marshmallow           current*              N/A: Launched 2015-09
Nexus 6P            6.0.0 Marshmallow           current*              N/A: Launched 2015-09
Pixel C             6.0.1 Marshmallow           current*              N/A: Launched 2015-12

*current version is 6.0.1 Marshmallow
```

So starting with the Nexus 4, devices have averaged 2.5 years between their release and final update.  You should add on a few months to account for the fact that there was some time between their final updates and when that version was actually obsoleted by the next.  And the 5 and 7(2013) have passed that mark, though they will probably not [get Android N](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/139232/1465).

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus and specific device pages linked there
- https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, [2 years](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?hl=en).

> Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P, Nexus 6, Nexus 5, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Nexus 9, and
>   Nexus 10 devices get the latest version of Android directly from
>   Google. These devices will receive Android version updates for at
>   least two years from when the device first became available on the
>   Google Store.

And as far as what Nexus device got what versions, that information is easy to find online. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus