# Can I run Android Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

So I just ordered a new phone (Honor 5x) I need to know can I install an early version of Nougat & when its released will it operate on my phone? Thanks!

Comment: Please see: [When will my device get the Android 7.0 update (Nougat)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/139232/16575) (which is our generic page for this question) If your device isn't listed there yet, we probably have not yet obtained data on it. If it's not released for your device officially, there might be some custom ROM for it one day; but such things are better checked at XDA, where most of the custom ROM creators are active.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a Nexus phone currently, you cannot run it.  When it is released, the manufacturer of your device will release it so I assume it will then operate on your phone.