# Cannot update to Lollipop version in moto G(2nd Generation)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

I didn't get any notification about the OS upgrade, Also I tried from my phone's Settings(Settings->About phone->System update). It resulted same there.

Kindly help me to upgrade to Lollipop version.

Comment: Look at [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-5-0-update-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

As instructed in the [Moto G (2nd Generation) - Android™ 5.0  Lollipop - Release Notes](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/102639) :

> **INSTRUCTIONS**
>
> For a successful installation, we recommend installing this update
>   when the battery in your phone is at least 50% charged and you are
>   connected to a Wi-Fi network.
>
> If you have received a notification
>   message for this update:
>
> 1. Select "Yes, I’m in".
> 2. After the software is downloaded, select "Install now".
> 3. After the software is installed, your phone will re-start automatically.
> 4. Your phone is now updated with 22.21.25
>
> If you have not received a notification message for this update,
>   follow the steps below to manually update your phone:
>
> 1. Select the Settings icon in the apps menu.
> 2. Select "About phone".
> 3. Select "System updates".
> 4. Select "Yes, I’m in". After the software is downloaded, select "Install now".
> 5. After the software is installed, your phone will re-start automatically.
> 6. Your phone is now updated to 22.21.25
>
> **Additional Information**
>
> If you have difficulty with this upgrade, visit us at
>   [www.motorola.com/mymotog](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/product_page/faqs/p/30,6720,9151/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDM5NDEzNjM4L3NpZC9QZHh5U0x0bQ%3D%3D).