# Will LG Optimus Exceed update to Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, updates, lg

The LG Optimus Exceed ships with KitKat 4.4.2. Will that automatically update to Lollipop, or would I need to root the phone?

[http://www.amazon.com/LG-Optimus-Exceed-Verizon-Prepaid/dp/B00K2XX4OY/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1439610488&sr=8-3&keywords=prepaid+android](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K2XX4OY)

Comment: [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684)

Comment: A quick search on Google doesn't show any result if the device will be updated to Lollipop, so we can only guess "no", unless there's official announcement from LG itself. Rooting the phone itself won't help if there's no custom ROM based on Lollipop for this device too.