# Installing Jelly bean 4.3 on Micro digit tablet

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

I just bought this China made tablet(Micro digit M7502). Jelly bean 4.2.2 is installed on it. But I want to upgrade it in to 4.3. Do any one know here? I think this is the right place to ask. Thank you.

Comment: Pointers: [When will my device get the Android 4.3 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49832/16575) / [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) / [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the manufacturer has not provided any OTA updates for your device.

Any chance of getting Android 4.3 would be by rooting it and installing a custom ROM.

After some searching, I found that there are no custom ROMs for your device. So you can proceed by submitting a request to the developers at [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com) to build one specifically for your device. Remember that flashing a ROM not meant for your device can result in bricking.