# Has Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean officially released for the Samsung Galaxy SIII?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean)

Does anyone know if Android 4.1.2 has been released officially for the Samsung Galaxy S3? If so, where can I download it?

I only want the official version.

Answer (score 0):

If it has been released officially, then it will be available either OTA or via a Kies update - however, I am not 100% sure whether or not it has been released, I would say it hasn't - but don't quote me on that.