# Galaxy Ace Duos S6802 jelly bean support

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean)

Is Android 4.1.X support available on Galaxy Ace Duos S6802? Can the device be successfully upgraded to Jelly Bean?

Comment: There's instructions here http://mobotechie.com/android/how-to-update-samsung-galaxy-ace-duos-s6802-to-android-4-2-1-jellybean-ultimate-guide on how to do it however in the comments it seems people are having some problems with them.

Comment: @ce4 That's for official releases though isn't it? Whereas the answer to this could be if someone's ported it. If OP if after an official release then one isn't available, the hardware was deemed not suitable to run JB. --edit My bad, just the top phones have official releases, there's unofficial ones for phones under them though, I should read things more carefully.

Comment: @Peanut: No, we also include unofficial builds in that canonical answer. Otherwise, this site would be peppered with questions just like this (more than it already is).

Comment: @AlEverett Yeah see my edit, released after I read it more closely, had only glanced at the top few phones. I'll flag ones like this as duplicates from now on then.

Comment: @Peanut Thanks for the Link... This was for developement purpose.. and not just to get a insight when will the device get an upgrade :)