# Xperia U and Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I've searched and got many results. Some people were telling JB for Xperia U would be comming soon. Some were telling never. Is is possible to port Jelly Bean in XPERIA U? Did anyone succeed yet?

Comment: [According to Sony, they are never going to release an official upgrade to 4.1 JB for the Xperia U](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/2012/12/17/update-on-sony-software-upgrades-including-uplift-to-jelly-bean-android-4-1-for-2012-xperia-smartphones-2/)

Comment: You might also refer to the question [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-1-update-jelly-bean), which contains a listing of devices and anticipated released or confirmation of no forthcoming update.

Comment: As for your other question, see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)