# Can i upgrade to jelly Bean?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, custom-roms, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have a [Zigo EON 5i](http://www.zigomobiles.com/products/eon5i.html). It runs ICS 4.0.4, has 512 MB RAM, a 1 GHz proccesor – ARM v7, Powervr and 128 MB internal memory.

Can I flash and add a custom rom? And if so, which one? I need Jelly Bean.

Comment: Take a look at the [info for the 'custom-rom' tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/custom-rom/info) to learn more.

Comment: Special recommendation from the list recommended by Dan: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). If you find a ROM there which is explicitly mentioned as for your device, there certainly should be a possibility to flash it.

Comment: See also: [When will my device get the Android 4.1 update (Jelly Bean)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24575)

Answer (score 0):

no they have jelly beans for ther nebula 6.9 and eon 6i but they are not palaning on making a rom to upgrade eon 5i..and going for a custom rom that created for another brand /model is such a risk.and personally im think that jelly beans will not suit the eon5i bcs its lack of low internal memory however Zigo technical crew  is much friendly once i've soft bricked my 5i by system change.and though didnt had a rom  bakup.and had go to service center they are very frindly and rooted by themself after resoftware.anyway if you need any help regarding rooting Zigo come to my group and feel free to ask questions.im still learning about roms and methods.
[here is my group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/119pc)

Comment: Can you please re-edit your answer - its poorly written.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you should contact the manufacturer.

Comment: They doesn't got any answer. because they will not create official jelly bean rom...

Comment: And they for sure won't help a customer installing a *Custom ROM* -- as that usually goes with rooting, and thus (outside the EU) voids the device's warranty.