# Samsung Galaxy Ace - HID Bluetooth Keyboard Connection?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, samsung-galaxy-ace

I'm a newly arrived escapee from the iPhone Empire - I just got a Galaxy Ace and it seems better in all respects except one very important one for me... I used to use my iPhone to write / take notes etc, using an I-connex Bluetooth keyboard.   But it looks like my Ace won't allow this keyboard to connect - it says it doesn't connect to HID devices.

I've tried two different apps to try and fix this - BlueKeyboard JP (which only works with certain keyboards, not including mine) and Bluetooth Keyboard Easyconnect (which I think requires my phone to be rooted - at any rate, it doesn't work).

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions how I can fix this, as it really makes the phone seriously less good than what I had before, given how I use it!   Failing that I'd be very grateful if anyone could advise me if there is any version of Android that DOES allow HID devices to connect - and what phones run it.

Comment: Your device does include bluetooth support, however not the HID profile (with the Android version it runs). I only see 3 options: a) Wait until Samsung launches a firmware update ([not happening](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich), alas). b) Install a mod ([Howto](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace:_Full_Update_Guide), download [here](http://get.cm/?device=cooper) or [search](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1167) XDA). c) live without it??

Comment: You can get better solutions for your problem, if you mention the model number and android version, which your device is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth was enabled early on in Android (1.5 or 1.6 iirc) So any limitation in that regards is from your specific device and not the platform itself.

I have successfully used HID bluetooth devices with: Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and HTC Evo 4g LTE, Toshiba Thrive, Acer Iconia A200.

I was unaware that there were any devices that disallowed HID device connections actually.

In general though Nexus [anything] devices are the least limited devices on the market at any given time, so I'd say you can't go wrong with one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth HID support was officially added to Android in Honeycomb 3.1. Any device that uses either this version or Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0 -> ) or Jelly Bean (future devices) supports Bluetooth keyboards out of the box.