# Can I run ICS on the Samsung Galaxy S+ I9001?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I have read a lot of documentation about how to run ICS on the Samsung Galaxy S I9000. Can I use the same approaches for the S+? Or is it not possible to run ICS on the S+?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galaxy S Plus i9001 looks like the i9000 however it has completely different internals:

- side by side [comparison](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=3908&idPhone2=3115) at gsmarena.com
- different CPU (1.4GHz Qualcomm Snapdragon vs. 1GHz Samsung Hummingbird)
- different GPU (Adreno vs PowerVR)
- different baseband modules (the i9001 has faster HSDPA)
- better battery, less internal space (512MB vs 2GB for the i9000)

**Most importantly**, the i9000 is well supported while the i9001's community support is rather poor. There's no official CM port for it. See the [i9001's forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1270) at XDA-developers.com. Regarding the approaches: Yes, you can use the same tools and your knowledge for the i9000. Just not the same ROM downloads.

Comment: So bottom line is there are ROMs but there unstable and do not support the phones full functionality ?

Comment: I have no idea how usable the most stable rom is,  just saw those alpha  tags in some of the rom thread titles. If you want to know more, just read them and see how serious the bugs are.